# Android ViewPager - Show preview of page on left and right

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using Android's `ViewPager`. What I want to do is to show a preview of the page on both the left and the right. I've seen where I can use a negative `pageMargin` to show a preview of the right side.

```
setPageMargin(-100);
```

Is there anyway that I can show a preview of the left side aswell? Its basically something similar to the gallery widget that I am looking for.

Comment: Good question! I have recently checked the source and I feel there is no better way if you don't want to modify the src code. Does the `setPageMargin(-100)` work correctly?

Comment: the GalleryView will do the job better, unless if you are using the ViewPger with fragments.

Comment: I was able to do this using the gallery view. same as viewpager in any way. don't know why gallery is deprecated

Comment: This question has since been extensively covered in the [post here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914609/viewpager-with-previous-and-next-page-boundaries

Comment: i am using Vierpager with fragments.So can i used same approach ?

Comment: if you want implement with `ViewPager2` then check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58056129/7666442

Answer (score 220):

To show preview of left and right pages set the following two values

1. `viewpager.setClipToPadding(false);`
2. `viewpager.setPadding(left,0,right,0);`

If you need space between two pages in the viewpager then add

```
viewpager.setPageMargin(int);
```

Comment: Yes I agree with you Jiju Induchoodan.. For more info please refer http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/14/android-tip-viewpager-with-protruding-children/
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914609/viewpager-with-previous-and-next-page-boundaries

Comment: Cool, it's so simple :) Is there possible to resize previews on right and left sizes on switch pages of view pager? For example - if fragment out of focus - it's scale will be ~0.8, but when we drag it to center - scale will increase to 1, and previous fragment from centre view will change scale to 0.8 when going out of screen?

Comment: This is working! But when I try to zoom the center layout, its zooming to top and bottom. The left and right is not visible due to the padding. Please see the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52710076/android-pinch-to-zoom-layout-inside-a-viewpager-with-padding-left-and-right

Answer (score 199):

## Solution with the new ViewPager2

Nowadays you should consider using [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2) which *"replaces ViewPager, addressing most of its predecessor’s pain-points"*:

> - Based on RecyclerView
> - RTL (right-to-left) layout support
> - Vertical orientation support
> - Reliable Fragment support (including handling changes to the underlying Fragment collection)
> - Dataset change animations (including `DiffUtil` support)

### The result

[image]

### The code

In your Activity/Fragment, setup the ViewPager2:

```
// MyRecyclerViewAdapter is an standard RecyclerView.Adapter :)
viewPager2.adapter = MyRecyclerViewAdapter() 

// You need to retain one page on each side so that the next and previous items are visible
viewPager2.offscreenPageLimit = 1

// Add a PageTransformer that translates the next and previous items horizontally
// towards the center of the screen, which makes them visible
val nextItemVisiblePx = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.viewpager_next_item_visible)
val currentItemHorizontalMarginPx = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.viewpager_current_item_horizontal_margin)
val pageTranslationX = nextItemVisiblePx + currentItemHorizontalMarginPx
val pageTransformer = ViewPager2.PageTransformer { page: View, position: Float ->
    page.translationX = -pageTranslationX * position
    // Next line scales the item's height. You can remove it if you don't want this effect
    page.scaleY = 1 - (0.25f * abs(position))
    // If you want a fading effect uncomment the next line:
    // page.alpha = 0.25f + (1 - abs(position))
}
viewPager2.setPageTransformer(pageTransformer)

// The ItemDecoration gives the current (centered) item horizontal margin so that
// it doesn't occupy the whole screen width. Without it the items overlap
val itemDecoration = HorizontalMarginItemDecoration(
    context,
    R.dimen.viewpager_current_item_horizontal_margin
)
viewPager2.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration)
```

Add the `HorizontalMarginItemDecoration`, which is a trivial `ItemDecoration`:

```
/**
 * Adds margin to the left and right sides of the RecyclerView item.
 * Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27664023/4034572
 * @param horizontalMarginInDp the margin resource, in dp.
 */
class HorizontalMarginItemDecoration(context: Context, @DimenRes horizontalMarginInDp: Int) :
    RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    private val horizontalMarginInPx: Int =
        context.resources.getDimension(horizontalMarginInDp).toInt()

    override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State
    ) {
        outRect.right = horizontalMarginInPx
        outRect.left = horizontalMarginInPx
    }

}
```

Add the dimensions that control how much of the previous/next item is visible, and current item horizontal margin:

```
<dimen name="viewpager_next_item_visible">26dp</dimen>
<dimen name="viewpager_current_item_horizontal_margin">42dp</dimen>
```

[image]

Finally add the `ViewPager2` to your layout:

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

One important thing: a `ViewPager2` item must have `layout_height="match_parent"` (otherwise it throws an IllegalStateException), so you should do something like:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" <-- this!
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp">

        <!-- ... -->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

### PageTransformer examples

Google has added a guide on ViewPager2 that has 2 `PageTransformer` implementations that you can use as an inspiration: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2

### About the new ViewPager2

- [Announcement at Google I/O 2019](https://youtu.be/td3Kd7fOROw?t=1702)
- [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2)
- [Release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2)
- [Code sample](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/master/ViewPager2)
- [Migrate from ViewPager to ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration)

Comment: Same problem on oreo devices, padding start and end works as expected on other devices but oreo after ViewPager2. PageTransformer resolved the issue, paddings are still same and I had to add `viewpager.setPageTransformer { page, position ->
            page.translationX = -1 * position
        }`

Comment: I have to slightly move the view pager's page to get this effect

Comment: never mind, I forgot to add this line `setOffscreenPageLimit(1)` :)

Comment: This is the best solution I ever find. It works perfectly but yes DO NOT FORGOT to set  ViewPager2 's Item width, height to  MATCH_PARENT.

Comment: Do you have the source code/Github repo for the GIF you posted?

Comment: @akubi Unfortunately I cannot give you the code because it belongs to a private company. But note that you have all the code you need here.

Comment: This is the best solution, better than other tutorials i found online. Thanks for providing detailed comments

Comment: Not show left right page in rtl application

Comment: @AlbertVilaCalvo What about vericle viewPager? I am using verticle viewPager and wants to preview upper and lower items?

Answer (score 83):

**Update :- ViewPager 2.0**

Please use the following

```
viewPager2.setPageTransformer(new MarginPageTransformer(1500));
```

Also see, [Android ViewPager2 setPageMargin unresolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56114430/android-viewpager2-setpagemargin-unresolved)

**Old Answer**

The answer by @JijuInduchoodan is perfect and working. However, since I am relatively new to Android, it took me a while to understand & set it properly. So, I am posting this answer for future reference and help anyone else who is in same shoes as  me.

```
if (viewPager == null) 
        {
            
            // Initializing view pager
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpLookBook);
            
            // Disable clip to padding
            viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
            // set padding manually, the more you set the padding the more you see of prev & next page
            viewPager.setPadding(40, 0, 40, 0);
            // sets a margin b/w individual pages to ensure that there is a gap b/w them
            viewPager.setPageMargin(20);
        }
```

There's no need to set any width to the `ViewPager's` page in the adapter. There no additional code required to see previous & next page in `ViewPager`. However, if you want to add blank space at the top & bottom of the each page, you can set the following code to `ViewPager's` child page`s parent layout.

```
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
```

[image: Final ViewPager]

This will be the final look of the ViewPager.

Comment: i can not find `viewPager.setPageMargin(20);` with viewpager2. .

Comment: @MahmoudMabrok checkout this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56114430/android-viewpager2-setpagemargin-unresolved

Answer (score 29):

In 2017 such behaviour additionally can be easily achieved by using `RecyclerView` with [PagerSnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PagerSnapHelper.html) (added in version 25.1.0 of v7 support library):
￼

[image]

Sometime ago I needed such viewpager-like feature and prepared a tiny library:

[MetalRecyclerPagerView](https://github.com/sandrfx/MetalRecyclerPagerView) - you can find all the code along with examples there.

Mainly it consists of a single class file: [MetalRecyclerViewPager.java](https://github.com/sandrfx/MetalRecyclerPagerView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/sandrlab/widgets/MetalRecyclerViewPager.java) (and two xmls: [attrs.xml](https://github.com/sandrfx/MetalRecyclerPagerView/blob/master/library/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml) and [ids.xml](https://github.com/sandrfx/MetalRecyclerPagerView/blob/master/library/src/main/res/values/ids.xml)).

Hope it helps somebody and will save some hours :)

Comment: Off topic, because sometimes only pager is needed but Nice to know! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This is awesome. I already had tons of RecyclerView helper code. Just adding a simple `new PagerSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)` and I have page snapping.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this in xml file, just use below code:

```
 android:clipToPadding="false"
 android:paddingLeft="XX"
 android:paddingRight="XX"
```

> For example:

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp" />
```

> Note: If you need space between pages, set padding/margin to child fragments

Comment: I downvoted. sorry bro. It worked this time!! Upvoted again

Answer (score 14):

**Kotlin + ViewPager2**

[image]

I am late to the party but the above answers didn't work for me. So I am here to help others who are still looking for the answer.

1. Your XML:

   ```
        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/newsHomeViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   ```
2. Your item Layout root view should be like this:

   ```
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp_10"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
   ```
3. Your Activity/Fragment:

add this before setting your viewpager adapter

```
        newsHomeViewPager.apply {
        clipToPadding = false   // allow full width shown with padding
        clipChildren = false    // allow left/right item is not clipped
        offscreenPageLimit = 2  // make sure left/right item is rendered
    }

    //increase this offset to show more of left/right
    val offsetPx =
        resources.getDimension(R.dimen.dp_30).toInt().dpToPx(resources.displayMetrics)
    newsHomeViewPager.setPadding(0, 0, offsetPx, 0)

    //increase this offset to increase distance between 2 items
    val pageMarginPx =
        resources.getDimension(R.dimen.dp_5).toInt().dpToPx(resources.displayMetrics)
    val marginTransformer = MarginPageTransformer(pageMarginPx)
    newsHomeViewPager.setPageTransformer(marginTransformer)
```

4. dp to pixel function:

   fun Int.dpToPx(displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics): Int = (this * displayMetrics.density).toInt()

**General Notes:**

1. I've to show the next page only, so in `setPadding` method, I've kept 0 for left and `offsetPx` for right. So add `offsetPx` to the right side also in the `setPadding` method if you wanted to show the right-side item too.
2. I've used dp from the dimension file, you can use your own.

Thank you, happy coding.

Comment: The last item has unnecessary padding. How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 9):

if someone still looking for solution, I had customized the ViewPage to achieve it without using negative margin, find a sample project here https://github.com/44kksharma/Android-ViewPager-Carousel-UI
it should work in most cases but you can still define page margin with
 `mPager.setPageMargin(margin in pixel);`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### Solution with Kotlin Extention for ViewPager2

---

1. Single Line Implementation in your Activity or Fragment.

   ```
   binding.viewpager2.setPreviewBothSide(R.dimen._20sdp,R.dimen._35sdp)
   ```
2. Add Below Code in `HorizontalMarginItemDecoration.kt` file in your Project

   ```
   import android.content.Context
   import android.graphics.Rect
   import android.view.View
   import androidx.annotation.DimenRes
   import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
   import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2

   class HorizontalMarginItemDecoration(context: Context, @DimenRes horizontalMarginInDp: Int) :
       RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
       private val horizontalMarginInPx: Int =
           context.resources.getDimension(horizontalMarginInDp).toInt()

       override fun getItemOffsets(
           outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State
       ) {
           outRect.right = horizontalMarginInPx
           outRect.left = horizontalMarginInPx
       }
   }

   fun ViewPager2.setPreviewBothSide(@DimenRes nextItemVisibleSize: Int,@DimenRes currentItemHorizontalMargin: Int) {
       this.offscreenPageLimit = 1
       val nextItemVisiblePx = resources.getDimension(nextItemVisibleSize)
       val currentItemHorizontalMarginPx = resources.getDimension(currentItemHorizontalMargin)
       val pageTranslationX = nextItemVisiblePx + currentItemHorizontalMarginPx
       val pageTransformer = ViewPager2.PageTransformer { page: View, position: Float ->
           page.translationX = -pageTranslationX * position
           page.scaleY = 1 - (0.25f * kotlin.math.abs(position))
       }
       this.setPageTransformer(pageTransformer)

       val itemDecoration = HorizontalMarginItemDecoration(
           context,
           currentItemHorizontalMargin
       )
       this.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration)
   }
   ```
3. And Yes Here you got this Amazing Output

   [image]

This Answer Optimized version of [Albert Vila Calvo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58088398/5773037) Answer

Comment: What about vericle viewPager? I am using verticle viewPager and wants to preview upper and lower items?

Comment: @krupaparekh you can try to modify the above answer (I give you a hint) if there is mentioned width you can replace it with height, and left-right replace with top-bottom and modify x to y and y to x in the above answer.

Answer (score 4):

For those struggling to have this on different screens,

```
mPager.setClipToPadding(false);
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
self.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int paddingToSet = width/4; //set this ratio according to how much of the next and previos screen you want to show.
mPager.setPadding(paddingToSet,0,paddingToSet,0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the author of [this article](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/android-viewpager2-show-partial-preview-of-left-and-right/). It's the best solution I found.

Just create a function eg. in your `Helpers` class like:

```
fun ViewPager2.showHorizontalPreview(offsetDpLeft : Int, offsetDpRight : Int, marginBtwItems : Int){
        this.apply {
            clipToPadding = false   // allow full width shown with padding
            clipChildren = false    // allow left/right item is not clipped
            offscreenPageLimit = 2  // make sure left/right item is rendered
        }

        // increase this offset to show more of left/right
        val offsetPxLeft = offsetDpLeft.toPx()
        val offsetPxRight = offsetDpRight.toPx()
        this.setPadding(offsetPxLeft, 0, offsetPxRight, 0)

        // increase this offset to increase distance between 2 items
        val pageMarginPx = marginBtwItems.toPx()
        val marginTransformer = MarginPageTransformer(pageMarginPx)
        this.setPageTransformer(marginTransformer)
    }
```

and call it like:

```
mViewPager.showHorizontalPreview(40,40,5)
```

in your Activity/Fragment

Answer (score 0):

Note that when setting none zero paddings to a viewpager, the viewpager's edgeeffect placement is messed up, this is a bug of the viewpager, see here:[viewpager edgeeffect bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68494185#comment1)

You can either disable the edge effect by setting `android:overScrollMode="never"` to the viewpager, or you can fix the bug with a slightly modified version of the EdgeEffect class:[ViewPagerEdgeEffect fix](https://github.com/ssynhtn/WrapContentViewPager/blob/master/wrapcontentviewpager/src/main/java/com/ssynhtn/wrapcontentviewpager/ViewPagerEdgeEffect.java)

Answer (score 0):

```
 override fun getPageWidth(position: Int): Float {
    return 0.7f
}
```

Add this in adapter class file, This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jiju's answer, if you want to set margin between pages for VIEWPAGER 2, please use the code like this:

```
viewpager.setPageTransformer(new MarginPageTransformer(14));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the XML file you should set paddings like so:
[image]

in the fragment:

```
int margin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20*2,     getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

and to have it all set, use this

```
myViewPager.setPageMargin(-margin);
```

should do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Tried and tested using ViewPager2.
Use below code to achieve what you want with few lines of code.

> ```
>     val SPACE_BETWEEN_CARD = 40
>     account_details_viewpager.setClipToPadding(false)
>     account_details_viewpager.setClipChildren(false)
>     account_details_viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3)
>     account_details_viewpager.getChildAt(0).setOverScrollMode(RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
>     val compositePageTransformer = CompositePageTransformer()
>     compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(MarginPageTransformer(SPACE_BETWEEN_CARD))
>     compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(ViewPager2.PageTransformer() {
>             page: View, position: Float ->
>         var r :Float = 1f-Math.abs(position)
>         page.setScaleY(0.85f + r * 0.15f)
>     })
>     account_details_viewpager.setPageTransformer(compositePageTransformer)
> ```

Here "account_details_viewpager" is view of ViewPager2

Comment: Additionally, if you want alpha on back pages of viewpager then use this line 

page.alpha = 0.25f + (1 - abs(position))

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot, I found two working ways for the view pager2
1.

```
         val pageMargin= 90;
         val pageOffset = 3;
   val transformer = CompositePageTransformer()
        transformer.addTransformer { page, position ->
            val ratio = position * -abs(2 * pageOffset + pageMargin)
            val scaleFactor =
                0.7f.coerceAtLeast(1 - abs(position - 0.14f))
            page.translationX = ratio
            page.scaleY = scaleFactor
        }
        binding.viewPager.setPageTransformer(transformer)
```

2. You can do it for each position

```
         val pageMargin= 70;
         val pageOffset = 3;
         binding.viewPager.setPageTransformer { page, position ->
             val myOffset = (position * -(2 * pageOffset + pageMargin)).toFloat()
             if (position < -1) {
                 page.translationX = -myOffset
             } else if (position <= 1) {
                 val scaleFactor =
                     0.7f.coerceAtLeast(1 - abs(position - 0.14285715f))
                 page.translationX = myOffset
                 page.scaleY = scaleFactor
                 page.alpha = scaleFactor
             } else {
                 page.alpha = 0F
                 page.translationX = myOffset
             }
         }
```

Answer (score -13):

Use this fragment adapter and class to view the viewpager in left and right scroll.add necessary classes to scroll to view next pages.

```
package com.rmn.viewpager;

import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The <code>PagerAdapter</code> serves the fragments when paging.
 * @author mwho
 */
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;
    /**
     * @param fm
     * @param fragments
     */
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem(int)
     */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}



package com.manishkpr.viewpager;


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Context _context;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);  
        _context=context;

        }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment f = new Fragment();
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            f=LayoutOne.newInstance(_context);  
            break;
        case 1:
            f=LayoutTwo.newInstance(_context);  
            break;
        }
        return f;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

}
```