# RecyclerView - Pressed state of items is getting messed up

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I create a `RecyclerView` like following:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), cols, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, stickToBottom);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

// completely disable animations... just to test if this solves the problem
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

I long press a icon and start scrolling and sometimes, this results in recycled views looking pressed... I'm using a simple `"android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` on my recyclerview items.

How can I solve the problem or what can be the root cause of this?

**some facts**

- recycling views works perfectly, texts and images update as they should
- ONLY the backgrounds are not resettet and look pressed even if the item is not touched...
- I'm using the `RecyclerView` in the `WindowManager` not in an activity..

Comment: android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true" http://stackoverflow.com/a/25011355/1584100

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/highlight_color" />

</selector>
```

Set this drawable to row_layout which you have used. It will work.

Comment: I tried a drawable without animations as well already... and it does not solve the problem. I had the idea, that the animations in the selector make problems...

Comment: @prom85 It worked for me. I did the drag and Drop functionality with this and other stuff for RecyclerView