# When to use ListView instead of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-recyclerview

I've been reading about `RecyclerView` and it's advantages over `ListView` And I got the difference between them.

What I don't get is when to use ListView and when to use RecyclerView. And is the RecyclerView meant to replace ListView? Do I have to replace all my ListViews with RecyclerViews?

Comment: "when to use ListView and when to use RecyclerView" -- if you need some of the advanced capabilities of `RecyclerView` (e.g., animated effects as you add/remove items), use `RecyclerView`. "Do I have to replace all my ListViews with RecyclerViews?" -- no.

Comment: check the thread: [Should we use RecyclerView to replace ListView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392554/should-we-use-recyclerview-to-replace-listview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is the RecyclerView meant to replace ListView?

Yes.

> Do I have to replace all my ListViews with RecyclerViews?

No.

> What I don't get is when to use ListView and when to use RecyclerView.

My recommendation is to use only `RecyclerView` for lists going forward. It is meant as a replacement for `ListView`, and it is a fantastic one at that. I would expect `RecyclerView` to continue to receive updates, but `ListView` will likely remain more or less as it is right now.

`ListView` isn't going anywhere because there are far too many applications that use it. Google can't just remove it because that would prevent most existing apps from compiling with the latest SDK. Deprecating it also isn't ideal because converting a `ListView` to a `RecyclerView` is a non-trivial amount of work and there isn't anything particularly broken with `ListView`.

Comment: Hi Tanis,   could you please check my question [Should we use RecyclerView to replace ListView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392554/should-we-use-recyclerview-to-replace-listview) and give comprehensive answer

Answer (score 1):

RecyclerView is the successor of ListView - so you should use it for all new code - but there is no immanent need to replace all ListViews now

Answer (score 0):

For me, `ListView` is more used in functional scenario, because it has built-in `setOnItemClickListener()` and `setMultiChoiceModeListener()` (multiselection mode), which are lack of in `RecyclerView`. On the other hand, `RecyclerView` is more used in display scenario, because it supports drag and drop funcitonality (built-in animation).