# When is implementing RecyclerView absolutely necessary?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

I am making an app with 100 list items and was wondering if I could get away with not implementing the RecyclerView as I find it hard to implement it.

Comment: Check this post [Should we use RecyclerView to replace ListView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392554/should-we-use-recyclerview-to-replace-listview)

Answer (score 1):

Quite frankly it depends up to you, `Listview` makes  it easy for you by taking a lot of responsibility which makes it slow at time when you have to show a lot of data, on other hand `RecyclerView` does what it is best at make's things fast by taking care or bare minimum structure.

`RecyclerView` is quite easy to implement and you will get chance to learn some of the touch framework of Android because of it.

And performing Animation on `RecyclerView` is quite easy as well and way better than `Listview`

Making a custom listview is piece of cake with `RecyclerView`

here's an example for `RecyclerView`

```
 private RecyclerView recyclerView;
recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    MyViewComplainAdapter adapter = new MyViewComplainAdapter(getApplicationContext(), createComplainList());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
```

in XML

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

your Adapter (Whatever you want to call this thing... lol )

```
 private class MyViewComplainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewComplainAdapter.MyViewComplainViewHolder>{

    private Context _Context;
    private ArrayList<ViewMyComplainData> _List;
    private LayoutInflater _Inflater;

    public MyViewComplainAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ViewMyComplainData> list){
        _Context = context;
        _List = list;
        _Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(_Context);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewComplainViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layout = _Inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item_view_my_complain,parent,false);
        MyViewComplainViewHolder holder = new MyViewComplainViewHolder(layout);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewComplainViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ViewMyComplainData data = _List.get(position);
        holder.complaint_number.setText(data.getComplaint_Number()+"");
        holder.complaint_type.setText(data.getComplaint_Type()+"");
        holder.status.setText(data.getStatus()+"");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return _List.size();
    }

    public class MyViewComplainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView complaint_number;
        TextView complaint_type;
        TextView status;

        public MyViewComplainViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            complaint_number = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_complaint_number_single_item_view_my_complain);
            complaint_type = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_complaint_type_single_item_view_my_complain);
            status= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_status_single_item_view_my_complain);
        }
    }
}
```

yes you will have to make a `ArrayList<ViewMyComplainData>` using this  method createComplainList(), you should figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking,  RecyclerView doesn't need anything like "notifyDataSetChanged()" when an item is added or deleted from your List, which is a huge improvement performance-wise.