# What's the enhancement of RecyclerView over ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

`RecyclerView` is added into `v7 support library` since Android API 22 officially. And many people said that it is a enhancement over `ListView` and many brief introductions to the usage of it were posted over the internet. But most of these articles are very simple, shallow and hollow. The enhancement is just `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, `RecyclerView.ItemAnimator` or `RecylerView.SmoothScroller`? Did the `recycling and reuse mechanism` of items' views during scrolling differ from the `ListView`'s? And what exactly is the `enhancement` of `RecyclerView` over `ListView`?

Any answers, tips or links are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can read [This](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/first-glance-androids-recyclerview/).

Comment: It doesn't steal your focus from the elements that are displayed within the recycler view, that's for certain. So you can have clickable elements without having tom ess with it

Comment: Check this [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392554/should-we-use-recyclerview-to-replace-listview)

Comment: "RecyclerView is added in Android API 22 officially" -- no, it is not. It is part of the Android Support package, in the `recyclerview-v7` library. It was introduced in tandem with Android 5.0 (API Level 21).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the official documentation `RecyclerView` is a major enhancement over `ListView`. It contains many new features like `ViewHolder`, `ItemDecorator`, `LayoutManager`, and `SmoothScroller`. But one thing that certainly gives it an edge over the `ListView` is; the ability to have animations while adding or removing an item.

**View Holders**

> In `ListView`, defining view holders was a suggested approach for
>   keeping references for views. But it was not a compulsion. Although by
>   not doing so, `ListView` used show stale data. Another major drawback of
>   not using view holders could lead to a heavy operation of finding
>   views by ids every time. Which resulted in laggy `ListView`s.
>
> This problem is solved in `RecylerView` by the use of
>   [RecyclerView.ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html) class. This is one of the major differences in
>   `RecyclerView` and `ListView`. When implementing a `RecyclerView` this class
>   is used to define a `ViewHolder` object which is used by the adapter to
>   bind `ViewHolder` with a position. Another point to be noted here, is
>   that while implementing the adapter for `RecyclerView`, providing a
>   `ViewHolder` is compulsory. This makes the implementation a little
>   complex, but solves the issues faced in `ListView`.

**Layout Manager**

> When speaking of `ListView`s, only one type of `ListView` is available
>   i.e. the vertical `ListView`. You cannot implement a `ListView` with
>   horizontal scroll. I know there are ways to implement a horizontal
>   scroll, but believe me it was not designed to work that way.
>
> But now when we look at Android `RecyclerView` vs `ListView`, we have
>   support for horizontal collections as well. In-fact it supports
>   multiple types of lists. To support multiple types of lists it uses
>   `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` class. This is something new that ListView
>   does not have. `RecyclerView` supports three types of predefined Layout
>   Managers:
>
> **LinearLayoutManager** – This is the most commonly used layout manager in
>   case of RecyclerView. Through this, we can create both horizontal and
>   vertical scroll lists. 
> **StaggeredGridLayoutManager** – Through this
>   layout manager, we can create staggered lists. Just like the Pinterest
>   screen. 
> **GridLayoutManager**– This layout manager can be used to display
>   grids, like any picture gallery.

**Item Animator**

> Animations in a list is a whole new dimension, which has endless
>   possibilities. In a ListView, as such there are no special provisions
>   through which one can animate, addition or deletion of items. Instead
>   later on as android evolved [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) was suggested by
>   Google’s Chet Haase in this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MIfSxgsHIs) for animations in `ListView`.
>   On the other hand comparing Android `RecyclerView` vs `ListView`, it has
>   [RecyclerView.ItemAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html) class for handling animations. Through this
>   class custom animations can be defined for item addition, deletion and
>   move events. Also it provides a [DefaultItemAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DefaultItemAnimator.html), in case you don’t
>   need any customizations.

**Adapter**

> `ListView` adapters were simple to implement. They had a main method
>   `getView` where all the magic used to happen. Where the views were bound
>   to a position. Also they used to have an interesting method
>   [registerDataSetObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#registerDataSetObserver%28android.database.DataSetObserver%29) where one can set an observer right in the
>   adapter. This feature is also present in RecyclerView, but
>   [RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver.html) class is used for it. But the point
>   in favor of ListView is that it supports three default implementations
>   of adapters:
> `ArrayAdapter` 
> `CursorAdapter` 
> `SimpleCursorAdapter` 
> Whereas `RecyclerView`
>   adapter, has all the functionality that `ListView` adapters had except
>   the built in support for DB cursors and ArrayLists. In
>   `RecyclerView.Adapter` as of now we have to make a custom implementation
>   to supply data to the adapter. Just like a BaseAdapter does for
>   `ListView`s. Although if you wish to know more about `RecyclerView`
>   adapter implementation, please refer to [Android RecyclerView Example](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-recyclerview-tutorial/).

**Item Decoration**

> To display custom dividers in a ListView, one could have easily added
>   these parameters in the ListView XML:
>   `android:divider="@android:color/transparent"`
>   `android:dividerHeight="5dp"` 
> The interesting part about Android
>   RecyclerView is that, as of now it does not show a divider between
>   items by default. Although the guys at Google must have left this out
>   for customization, intentionally. But this greatly increases the
>   effort for a developer. If you wish to add a divider between items,
>   you may need to do a custom implementation by using
>   [RecyclerView.ItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html) class. Or you can apply a hack by using
>   this file from official samples: [DividerItemDecoration.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/18728e9dd5dd66d4f5edf1b792e77e2b544a1cb0/sdk/extras/android/support/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/widget/decorator/DividerItemDecoration.java)

Answer (score 13):

> And what exactly is the enhancement of RecyclerView over ListView?

`RecyclerView` is not an "enhancement" "over `ListView`", strictly speaking. `ListView` actually does something; `RecyclerView`, on its own, does not. A more accurate comparison would be that the `RecyclerView` *framework* is an improvement over `AdapterView`, and to some extent the `AbsListView` parent class of `ListView` and `GridView`.

`RecyclerView` focuses on widget recycling and gross child `View` management. It delegates everything else to other classes. `AdapterView` does far less of this, making it more difficult to extend functionally.

Of note:

- Laying out the children, within the scrollable space of the `RecyclerView`, is delegated to managers. Hence, not only do three ship with `recyclerview-v7` (list, grid, staggered grid), but others can be developed for alternative scenarios (e.g., overlapping children, for a `StackView` or `Gallery` sort of experience).
- Updates from adapters can be *much* more fine-grained. With `AdapterView`, you pretty much have to redraw the entire view (e.g., a `ListView` and all its rows) on any change of significance, especially when adding and removing items. The update mechanism in the `RecyclerView` adapters indicate the specific positions that change. Not only does this require less processing time, but it helps enable the animated effects that `RecyclerView` offers (again, with pluggable replacements) for adding, moving, and removing items.
- Other stuff that was "baked into" `ListView`, like drawing dividers, is now pulled out into extension points, such as an `ItemDecorator`. Now, you can choose how to "decorate" items, with line dividers or boxes or colored bar separators or whatever. Decoration is not limited to "dividers", but can affect anything in the views that, for one reason or another, you consider to be separate from the item views themselves.

`RecyclerView`, though, is fairly complicated to get going. What you get from `ListView` "out of the box" takes a lot more code -- yours or a third-party library's -- to match. For experienced developers, this is a feature, in that the code is replaceable with other code. For newcomers, this is a bug, in that there is a steeper learning curve for `RecyclerView`, IMHO.

Comment: Lets not forget that now we can access REAL scroll values without dirty workarrounds.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. View Holders
>
>    RecylerView by the use of RecyclerView.ViewHolder class. This is one
>      of the major differences in RecyclerView and ListView. When
>      implementing a RecyclerView this class is used to define a ViewHolder
>      object which is used by the adapter to bind ViewHolder with a position
> 2. Layout Manager
>
>    support for horizontal collections as well. In-fact it supports
>      multiple types of lists. To support multiple types of lists it uses
>      RecyclerView.LayoutManager class. This is something new that ListView
>      does not have. RecyclerView supports three types of predefined Layout
>      Managers: LinearLayoutManager – This is the most commonly used layout
>      manager in case of RecyclerView. Through this, we can create both
>      horizontal and vertical scroll lists. StaggeredGridLayoutManager –
>      Through this layout manager, we can create staggered lists. Just like
>      the Pinterest screen. GridLayoutManager– This layout manager can be
>      used to display grids, like any picture gallery.
> 3. Item Animator
>
>    RecyclerView has RecyclerView.ItemAnimator class for handling
>      animations. Through this class custom animations can be defined for
>      item addition, deletion and move events. Also it provides a
>      DefaultItemAnimator, in case you don’t need any customizations.
> 4. Adapter
>
>    In RecyclerView.Adapter as of now we have to make a custom
>      implementation to supply data to the adapter. Just like a BaseAdapter
>      does for ListViews.

Source: http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-recyclerview-vs-listview-comparison/