# Go back to previous Activity with some `put extra` onClick of a recyclerView Item

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I want to pass an data previous activity on click of Item in Recycler view and show it on a Edit Text.

This is the code i have used to pass data from listview to the previous activity

I want to do the same thing with Recyclerview

//Calling Second Activity

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 100;
Intent dateintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(dateintent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

//onClick of listview pass the data back to previous activity

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                String str = txt.getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("data",str);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
                finish();

            }
```

});

//After getting data show the data in the first activity edit box

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String data= data.getStringExtra("data");
            if (data!= null) {
                edittext.setText(data);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Passing Data from one activity to previous activity i have tried, when i click on list-view item the data will be passed back to previous activity text-box. I want to do the same thing using recycler view

Answer (score 1):

First create this Interface

```
public interface RunnableValue {

public void run(Object obj);
}
```

2.This MainActivity add

```
 RunnableValue run=new RunnableValue() {
        @Override
        public Bundle run(Object obj) {

             String str = obj.toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("data",str);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
            finish();
          }
    };
    mAdapter = new SearchAdapter(dataSet,run);
```

3. This RecyclerView Adapter

   ```
   public SearchAdapter(List<String>  dataSet,RunnableValue runnableValue) {
       mDataSet = dataSet;
       this.runnableValue=runnableValue;
   }
   public static class SearchHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   private final TextView textView;

   public SearchHolder(View v) {
       super(v);

       v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

               runnableValue.run(getTextView().toString());
           }
       });
       textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtSearchItem);
   }

   public TextView getTextView() {
       return textView;
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Jacob's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26196831/1965698). This adds listener for RecyclerView. Then, do the same as you have done in ListView.

Comment: i want the data from recycler-view to be shown in the edit text in the previous activity on item click

Answer (score 0):

There is no `setOnItemClickListener` available in `RecyclerView`, so you need make your own click listener in your `RecyclerView` adaper, just check out the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392554/should-we-use-recyclerview-to-replace-listview), then you should be able to make it.

Hope this help!

Comment: The code i posted was using list-view which i have done

Comment: Yes, so I am talking `RecyclerView`, and the post is also for `RecyclerView`, is not it?

Comment: it's correct, but i am facing problem in passing the data from recycler view to previous activity on item click

Comment: You can do it in ViewHolder that has click listener

Comment: on click work's fine for me i can display the data in a toast message but i want to send that data back to previous activity

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView doesn't have a setOnItemClickListener like its predecessor ListView did. However, that shouldn't prevent us from doing what we want to do. So, we reinvent the wheel and make our very own OnItemClickListener for your RecyclerView. Here's a step by step guide.

1. **Create an interface called OnItemClickListener** by creating a new file called OnItemClickListener.java with an empty method called onItemClick.

   ```
   public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view , int position);
    }
   ```
2. **Create a static variable in your adapter called**

   ```
   static OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
   ```
3. **Setup onClickListener in your custom ViewHolder** with a call to our onItemClick method like so

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
      mItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, getPosition());
   }
   ```
4. **Create a public method called SetOnItemClickListener in your adapter class**

   ```
   public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener)
   {
   this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
   }
   ```
5. **SetOnItemClickListener on your custom RecyclerView Adapter**

   ```
   ((NameOfYourAdapter) mAdapter).SetOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                   if(view != null)
                   {
           TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
           String str = txt.getText().toString();
                       Intent intent = new Intent();
                       intent.putExtra("data",str);
                       setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                       //close this Activity...
                       finish();
                   }
               }
           });
   ```

That should do it. If you have any questions, feel free to ask!