# How to get the List size() from adapter and update Activity UI from recycler Adapter itself?

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have a delete button in my adapter call and *when i press the delete button* i want to

**1. remove the value from list** and,

**2. Update the size of the list in the main activity**

and . *Have tried using Interface where i referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182944/how-pass-data-from-recyclerview-to-activity)* but **it's not working** and i am so confused.

So can any one provide me an best way

**My Adapter Code:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final AddLineItem_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final AddLineItem_ListView addLineItem_listView = addLineItem_listViews.get(position);

    holder.tv_OrderID.setText(addLineItem_listView.getItemID());
    holder.tv_ProductName.setText(addLineItem_listView.getProductName());
    holder.tv_Quantity.setText(addLineItem_listView.getQuantity());
    holder.tv_UnitPrice.setText(addLineItem_listView.getUnitPrice());
    holder.tv_TotalAmount.setText(addLineItem_listView.getTotalAmount());

    holder.btn_Delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addLineItem_listViews.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

I want to update the `addLineItem_listView` size on the main activity in TextView.

Comment: where are you showing in the mainActivity ??

Comment: addLineItem_listViews.size()

Comment: Java is a statically typed language, there is zero reason to have a `tv_` prefix on your variables

Comment: i have implemented  `addLineItem_listViews.size()` manually with a button in my main activity but i want to display the `addLineItem_listViews.size()` without using button click

Comment: @EpicPandaForce this just for my understanding

Comment: have updated the answer.. please check..

Comment: @SantanuSur i am working on it Thanks sir

Comment: update if it works..

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly

Comment: I am getting so much discouraged of this negative vote.

Comment: Thanks @SantanuSur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create the interface..
- Pass it to the adapter..
- Call interface function after deleting (providing the size of list)

> **Create interface**

```
public interface ShowDeleted {

void showDeleted(int size);

}
```

> **Initialize the interface anonymously in the activity like this**

```
ShowDeleted showDeleted = new ShowDeleted() {
    @Override
    public void showDeleted(int size) {
         // show the changed list size or update UI
    }
};
```

> **Pass the interface to the recyclerAdapter**

`YourAdapter youradpter = new YourAdpater(context,list,showDeleted );`

> **Initialize the constructor of recyclerAdapter like this:-**

```
   public YourAdapter(Context context, YourList yourList, ShowDeleted 
                                                           showDeleted)
     {
            }
```

> **holder.onClick do this**

```
holder.btn_Delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        addLineItem_listViews.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        this.showDeleted.showDeleted(addLineItem_listViews.size());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use **view.setTag(position)**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final AddLineItem_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final AddLineItem_ListView addLineItem_listView = addLineItem_listViews.get(position);

    holder.tv_OrderID.setText(addLineItem_listView.getItemID());
    holder.tv_ProductName.setText(addLineItem_listView.getProductName());
    holder.tv_Quantity.setText(addLineItem_listView.getQuantity());
    holder.tv_UnitPrice.setText(addLineItem_listView.getUnitPrice());
    holder.tv_TotalAmount.setText(addLineItem_listView.getTotalAmount());
    holder.btn_Delete.setTag(position)
    holder.btn_Delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addLineItem_listViews.remove((Integer)v.getTag());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

use this function

```
 public void removeAt(int position) {
    list.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size());
}
```