# Set Title in Navigation View Menu Won't Work When Inflating Layout

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer

Why can't I set the title of the navigation view menu in my CandidateListAdapter.java when I inflate it? But in my MainActivity.java the code works perfectly fine

MainActivity.java

```
NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.right_nav_view);
    Menu menu = navView.getMenu();
    MenuItem logout = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_logout);
    logout.setTitle("asd");
```

CandidateListAdapter.java

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    nav = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_layout, null, false);
    NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) nav.findViewById(R.id.right_nav_view);
    Menu menu = navView.getMenu();
    MenuItem pres = menu.findItem(R.id.pres);
    pres.setTitle("Maria");
```

Comment: the link is not the solution i needed. I just want the menu item's title to be changed once I clicked the card in CandidateListAdapter

Comment: have updated my answer..ask if you have any problem..

Comment: check the update..

Answer (score 0):

**To access the Activity UI elements from the adapter.. you can use interface..and then you have to pass it to the adapter** ...follow this link

[How to get the List size() from adapter and update Activity UI from recycler Adapter itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48904077/how-to-get-the-list-size-from-adapter-and-update-activity-ui-from-recycler-ada/48904196#48904196)

**Update**

make the `navView` field variable of YourActivity and change the title from the interface method... pass the interface method a title like `changeTitle(String title);` and call it in adapter like :- `interface.changeTitle("Maria");`