# How to pass textview value from adapter class to texview of another acivity

Tags: java, android

I want to pass the value of textview from the adapter class to another textview of another activity.
please help me ...

//recycleradapter class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(applicationContext, DetailActivity.class);
            
            intent.putExtra("likes",holder.quantity.toString());
            applicationContext.startActivity(intent);
```

// detail acivity class

```
String like = getIntent().getStringExtra("Likes");
Toast.makeText(this, like+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
item_quantiy.setText(like);
```

Comment: What's the problem? Your cide should work

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps.

1. get the value from the adapter to the activity
2. Then send the data from this activity to the other

Use an interface to trigger when the item in the recyclerview in clicked

In the interface implementation in the activity get that data and pass it to the next activity via an intent like you're doing here

Comment: please give an example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47183138/13533028

Answer (score 0):

change

```
Intent intent = new Intent(applicationContext, DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("likes",holder.quantity.toString());
applicationContext.startActivity(intent);
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(applicationContext, DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("likes",holder.quantity.getText().toString());
applicationContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your key spelling. as you can see in your code the key is `likes` with small `l` and in your DetailActivity the key is `Likes` with capital `L`
Change the code as below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(applicationContext, DetailActivity.class);  
intent.putExtra("likes",holder.quantity.toString());
applicationContext.startActivity(intent);
```

to

```
String like = getIntent().getStringExtra("likes");
Toast.makeText(this, like, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
item_quantiy.setText(like);
```

or you can create a class to store your keys like below

```
public class SC{ 
     private static final String KEY_LIKE = "likes"
}
```

then you can call this key in any class like `SC.KEY_LIKE`

Answer (score -1):

in adapter use context or activity for intent .(instead applicationContext)

Comment: bro ,Context applicationContext and Context context are same , no diffrents

Comment: read documents android!!!