# Adapter onClickListener not firing when it should, or updating View correctly

Tags: android, adapter, android-arrayadapter

Help!  This was working, but no version control.

The scoring buttons are updating a TextView several rows down from the one being clicked, and Android Studio logs I put in to problem solve aren't even registering that a button has been hit.

The whole thing is going sideways, the question is 'why does hitting the plusButton and minusButton update a TextView in a row several down from the 'active' row where I want to update stuff.

Here's a picture, I've clicked on the bear 4 times, and it's updated Player 4's score TextView, wth?
[image]

```
package com.basketball.dating;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * {@link ScoreBoardAdapter} is an {@link ArrayAdapter} that can provide the layout for each list item
 * based on a data source, which is a list of {@link ScoreBoard} objects.
 */
public class ScoreBoardAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ScoreBoard>  {

    /** Resource ID for the background color for this list of words */
    private int mColorResourceId;

    final String TAG = "ScoreBoardAdapter";
    public ScoreHolder holder = new ScoreHolder();

    /**
     * Create a new {@link ScoreBoardAdapter} object.
     *
     * @param context is the current context (i.e. Activity) that the adapter is being created in.
     * @param scoreBoards is the list of {@link ScoreBoard}s to be displayed.
     */
    public ScoreBoardAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ScoreBoard> scoreBoards) {
        super(context, 0, scoreBoards);
        //mColorResourceId = new ContextCompat().getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorAccent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        //ScoreHolder holder = new ScoreHolder();

        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            // now stuff all the row's views into a ScoreHolder object
            holder.plusButton = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.plusButton);
            holder.minusButton = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.minusButton);
            holder.scoreTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.score_text_view);

            // now attach these details to the row, so it 'remembers' they're there
            listItemView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            Log.wtf("ScoreBoardADAPTER", "NOT_NULL ROW");
            holder = (ScoreHolder) listItemView.getTag();
        }
        holder.plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //private int pos = position;
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TextView mPlusButton = (TextView) v;
                Log.wtf(TAG, "hit increment " + position);
                int score = Integer.parseInt((String) holder.scoreTextView.getText());
                if (score < 99) {
                    holder.scoreTextView.setText(String.valueOf(score + 1));
                }
            }
        });
        holder.minusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //private int pos = position;
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TextView mMinusButton = (TextView) v;
                int score = Integer.parseInt((String) holder.scoreTextView.getText());
                holder.scoreTextView.setText(String.valueOf(score - 1));
            }
        });

        // Get the {@link Word} object located at this position in the list
        ScoreBoard currentScoreBoard = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID miwok_text_view.
        TextView playerNameTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.playerName);

        playerNameTextView.setText("Player " + String.valueOf(currentScoreBoard.getPlayerName()) );

        // Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the Avatar.
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.playerAvatar);
        // display the provided image based on the resource ID
        imageView.setImageResource(currentScoreBoard.getAvatar());
        // Make sure the view is visible
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // TODO adapt to colour the leaders gold, silver, bronze
//        // Set the theme color for the list item
//        View textContainer = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_container);
//        // Find the color that the resource ID maps to
//        int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorAccent);
//        // Set the background color of the text container View
//        textContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);

        // Return the whole list item layout so that it can be shown in the ListView.
        return listItemView;
    }

    /* need to be able to save an object of key textViews for each list item , or 'row' */
    static class ScoreHolder {
        TextView plusButton;
        TextView minusButton;
        TextView scoreTextView;
    }
}
```

Comment: consider using RecyclerView and it's own adapter. This one is kinda depricated and in this particular case I can't understand why this thing in working that way

Comment: @alexeypolusov `ListView` and `ArrayAdapter` are most certainly *not* deprecated. From one of the developers on the UI Toolkit Team; ["If ListView works for you, there is no reason to migrate"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28398488/5115932).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to not make this as a field of the adapter

```
public ScoreHolder holder = new ScoreHolder();
```

And I think the reason for you doing that is because you couldn't get a reference to the holder from within the onClick methods, and the IDE tried to make the holder effectively final, but that wasn't possible because you needed to assign the holder to two different things, so you just moved the holder to a field.

TL;DR Try putting it back into the getView method

```
View listItemView = convertView;
final ScoreHolder holder = listItemView == null ? new ScoreHolder() : listItemView.getTag();

    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
```

If that doesn't work (can't remember if ternary's work on final variables), then you can set the tag of the two buttons to be the holder as well, then get the holder in the two click listeners onClick methods from `v`

Comment: Hey Cricket, yep this is it, worthy of Sherlock.  I declare it locally in getView, it demands to be final so inner classes can access it, then that means I can't assign properties to it as needed.  I've refactored to pass my ScoreHolder functions to a helper 'setupButtons' function, and all is well.  Thanks everyone.  Can you beleive my internet router has died today too?  Gang Stackoverflow (and mobile tethering) will get me through!

Answer (score 0):

Your direct problem is that you have one single `ScoreHolder` object for the entire Adapter. There are several views created, but since they all use the same holder, all the `OnClickListeners` will change the `TextView` of the last created list row.

Most `AdapterViews`, including `ListView`, use a pool of `Views` for their items. The `convertView` parameter will most likely be `null` the first few times `getView` is called, and when the pool is full, you will start receiving non-null objects as `converView`s.

TL;DR: You have several list item `Views` sharing a single `ScoreHolder` object.