# Show ListView on MainActivity

Tags: java, android, listview

I have the method `show_list` that creates a `List` from some strings, after adds the `List` to `ArrayAdapter` and binds the adapter to `ListView`. Returns the `ListView` created. How can I add the `ListView` to `MainActivity` and show it?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private View show_list() {
        String[] data = {"Ionut","Eugeniu","George","Felix","Fazlidin"};
        List<String> data_list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(data));
        ArrayAdapter<String> data_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.list_item,data_list);
        ListView data_view = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        data_view.setAdapter(data_adapter);
        return data_view;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ionut.vremea2.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_view" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:text="Ionut"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list_item" />
```

Comment: It's 2016. Do not use ListView. Use RecyclerView.

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: Just call ur method show_list in the oncreate

Comment: Thank you :) I thought that I need to add it somehow

Comment: @SkyKelsey [You could read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392554/should-we-use-recyclerview-to-replace-listview#28398488) *If ListView works for you, there is no reason to migrate*

Comment: @cricket_007 Sure, s/he can continue to use a ListView. We'll hear of their next ListView bug very soon I predict! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `show_list()` in `onCreate()`

Comment: ... that's somewhat obvious... or move all the code from `show_list` into `onCreate`