# RecyclerView vs. ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

From android developer ([Creating Lists and Cards](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)):

> The RecyclerView widget is a more advanced and flexible version of
>   ListView.

Okay, it sounds cool, but when I saw this example picture, I got really confused about the difference between these two.

[image]

The picture above can be easily created by `ListView` using custom adapter.

So, in what situation should one use `RecyclerView`?

Comment: [first-glance-androids-recyclerview](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/first-glance-androids-recyclerview/)

Comment: @Dev786: I suggest that you add a comment here explaining in detail what you feel is missing from the **many** existing answers on this question.

Comment: As of 2021, ListView is listed in AndroidStudio under Legacy, while RecyclerView is under Common. The answers are ambiguous as to which one is easier to use, so for newbies like me I'd guess I better start with trying RecyclerView

Comment: Naming things in Android world is totally messed up. They should call it `RecyclerListView` or something.

Answer (score 445, accepted):

`RecyclerView` was created as a `ListView` improvement, so yes, you can create an attached list with `ListView` control, but using `RecyclerView` is easier as it:

1. **Reuses cells while scrolling up/down**  - this is possible with implementing View Holder in the `ListView` adapter, but it was an optional thing, while in the `RecycleView` it's the default way of writing adapter.
2. **Decouples list from its container** - so you can put list items easily at run time in the different containers (linearLayout, gridLayout) with setting `LayoutManager`.

*Example:*

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
//or
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
```

3. **Animates common list actions** - Animations are decoupled and delegated to `ItemAnimator`.

There is more about `RecyclerView`, but I think these points are the main ones.

So, to conclude, `RecyclerView` is a more flexible control for handling "list data" that follows patterns of delegation of concerns and leaves for itself only one task - recycling items.

Comment: Main responsibility of the list view is to 1.) visually arrange items within given area and preferably 2.) reuse items. 
With RecylerView this breaks into single responsibilities - recycle view recycles and it's given LayoutManager arranges items on the screen. 
In other words recycle view doesn't know/care where to put items on screen, it just takes care of recycling them.
From android doc: 
"By changing the LayoutManager a RecyclerView can be used to implement a standard vertically scrolling list, a uniform grid, staggered grids, horizontally scrolling collections and more. "

Comment: "Reuse cells while scrolling up/down" : As far I know this is completely wrong Because this happens even in listview without viewholder.

Comment: The main use of view holder in listview is Your code might call findViewById() frequently during the scrolling of ListView, which can slow down performance. Even when the Adapter returns an inflated view for recycling, you still need to look up the elements and update them. A way around repeated use of findViewById() is to use the "view holder" design pattern.

A ViewHolder object stores each of the component views inside the tag field of the Layout, so you can immediately access them without the need to look them up repeatedly.

Comment: What I try to say is Row will be recycled even when you implement listview without view holder. That is the property and advantage of listview. That is what they created listview.

Comment: they did nothing special, these features can be added by anyone. you can extend ListView and baseAdapter and add any feature to it if you want. there actually is no difference between these two.

Answer (score 49):

For list views to have good performance you'll need to implement the holder pattern, and that's easy to mess up especially when you want to populate the list with several different kinds of views.

The RecyclerView bakes this pattern in, making it more difficult to mess up.  It's also more flexible, making it easier to handle different layouts, that aren't straight linear, like a grid.

Comment: Yes ! , there should be more discussions on when *NOT* to use recyclerview too. If your rows have content dynamically added based on the model's data and you use Recycler view, BOOM.

Comment: You should be able to add dynamic content based on model data.  You'll just need to setup different views for any type of content you want to support.

Answer (score 45):

`ListView` is the ancestor to `RecyclerView`. There were many things that `ListView` either didn't do, or didn't do well.  If you were to gather the shortcomings of the `ListView` and solved the problem by abstracting the problems into different domains you'd end up with something like the recycler view. Here are the main problem points with ListViews:

- Didn't enforce `View` Reuse for same item types (look at one of the adapters that are used in a `ListView`, if you study the getView method you will see that nothing prevents a programmer from creating a new view for every row even if one is passed in via the `convertView` variable)
- Didn't prevent costly `findViewById` uses(Even if you were recycling views as noted above it was possible for devs to be calling `findViewById` to update the displayed contents of child views. The main purpose of the `ViewHolder` pattern in `ListViews` was to cache the `findViewById` calls.  However this was only available if you knew about it as it wasn't part of the platform at all)
- Only supported Vertical Scrolling with Row displayed Views (Recycler view doesn't care about where views are placed and how they are moved, it's abstracted into a `LayoutManager`. A Recycler can therefore support the traditional `ListView` as shown above, as well as things like the `GridView`, but it isn't limited to that, it can do more, but you have to do the programming foot work to make it happen).
- Animations to added/removed was not a use case that was considered.  It was completely up to you to figure out how go about this (compare the RecyclerView. Adapter classes notify* method offerings v. ListViews to get an idea).

In short `RecyclerView` is a more flexible take on the `ListView`, albeit more coding may need to be done on your part.

Answer (score 23):

> The `RecyclerView` is a new ViewGroup that is prepared to render any
>   adapter-based view in a similar way. It is supossed to be the
>   successor of **`ListView and GridView`**, and it can be found in the
>   `latest support-v7 version`. The **`RecyclerView`** has been developed
>   with *extensibility* in mind, so it is possible to create any kind of
>   layout you can think of, but not without a little pain-in-the-ass
>   dose.

Answer taken from [Antonio leiva](http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview/)

```
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
```

`RecyclerView` is indeed a **`powerful view`** than `ListView` .
For more details you can visit [This page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).

Comment: I like this sentence from your answer: **This is Android, so things are never easy** This is true for what the Android app development has been being, but I think it's just something wrong in how they designed the API as well as the patterns to build Android app. Theoretically a good design should hide all possible complexities from the programmers (but still be accessisble for advanced ones), what they commonly care is the business logic, data and other algorithms other than struggling with handling UI related problems (and more tedious problems currently present in Android development).

Answer (score 19):

Following are few key points/differences between RecyclerView & ListView. Take your call wisely.

> If ListView works for you, there is no reason to migrate. If you are
>   writing a new UI, you might be better off with RecyclerView.
>
> RecylerView has inbuilt ViewHolder, doesn't need to implement our own
>   like in listView. It support notify at particular index as well
>
> Things like animating the addition or removal of items are already
>   implemented in the RecyclerView without you having to do anything
>
> We can associate a layout manager with a RecyclerView, this can be
>   used for getting random views in recycleview while this was limitation
>   in ListView In a ListView, the only type of view available is the
>   vertical ListView. There is no official way to even implement a
>   horizontal ListView. Now using a RecyclerView, we can have a
>
> i) LinearLayoutManager - which supports both vertical and horizontal
>   lists, ii) StaggeredLayoutManager - which supports Pinterest like
>   staggered lists, iii) GridLayoutManager - which supports displaying
>   grids as seen in Gallery apps.
>
> And the best thing is that we can do all these dynamically as we want.

Answer (score 17):

Major advantage :

`ViewHolder` is not available by default in `ListView`. We will be creating explicitly inside the `getView()`.
`RecyclerView` has inbuilt `Viewholder`.

Answer (score 13):

Advantages of RecyclerView over listview :

1. Contains ViewHolder by default.
2. Easy animations.
3. Supports horizontal , grid and staggered layouts

Advantages of listView over recyclerView :

1. Easy to add divider.
2. Can use inbuilt arrayAdapter for simple plain lists
3. Supports Header and footer .
4. Supports OnItemClickListner .

Comment: As far as I understand you can easily add a divider to a recyclerView using `recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));` after doing something like `recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.feed);`

Comment: @nviens For list view you can add divider,adjust its height and change its color all in xml it self . Also  current implemention for divider is just ok , it was a nightmare to add divider for recyclerview previously , just check this answer to see how previous implementation for divider was https://stackoverflow.com/a/27037230/6478047

Answer (score 6):

I think the main and biggest difference they have is that `ListView` looks for the position of the item while creating or putting it, on the other hand `RecyclerView` looks for the type of the item. if there is another item created with the same type `RecyclerView` does not create it again. It asks first adapter and then asks to recycledpool, if recycled pool says "yeah I've created a type similar to it", then `RecyclerView` doesn't try to create same type. `ListView` doesn't have a this kind of pooling mechanism.

Answer (score 6):

**RecyclerView info**

The `RecyclerView` was introduced with `Android 5.0 (Lollipop)`. it is included in the [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html). Thus, it is compatible with Android API Level 7.

Similarly to the `ListView`, `RecyclerView’s` main idea is to provide listing functionality in a performance friendly manner. The ‘Recycler’ part of this view’s name is not there by coincidence. The `RecyclerView` can actually recycle the items with which it’s currently working. The recycling process is done thanks to a pattern called [View Holder](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html).

**Pros & Cons of RecyclerView**

**Pros:**

- integrated animations for adding, updating and removing items
- enforces the recycling of views by using the ViewHolder pattern
- supports both grids and lists
- supports vertical and horizontal scrolling
- can be used together with DiffUtil

**Cons:**

- adds complexity
- no OnItemClickListener

**ListView info**

The `ListView` has been around since the very beginning of Android. It was available even in `API Level 1` and it has the same purpose as the `RecyclerView`.

The usage of the ListView is actually really simple. In this aspect, it’s not like its successor. The learning curve is smoother than the one for the RecyclerView. Thus, it is easier to grasp. We don’t have to deal with things like the LayoutManager, ItemAnimator or DiffUtil.

**Pros & Cons of ListView**

**Pros:**

- simple usage
- default adapters
- available OnItemClickListener
- it’s the foundation of the `ExpandableListView`

**Cons:**

- doesn’t embrace the usage of the ViewHolder pattern

Answer (score 5):

In addition to above differences following are few more:

1. RV separates view creation and binding of data to view.
   In LV, you need to check if convertView is null or not for creating view, before binding data to it.
   So, in case of RV, view will be created only when it is needed but in case of LV, one can miss the check for convertview and will create view everytime.
2. Switching between Grid and List is more easy now with LayoutManager.
3. No need to notify and update all items, even if only single item is changed.
4. One had to implement view caching in case of LV.
   It is provided in RV by default. (There is difference between view caching n recycling.)
5. Very easy item animations in case of RV.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion `RecyclerView` was made to address the problem with the recycle pattern used in listviews because it was making developer's life more difficult.
All the other you could handle more or less.
For instance I use the same adapter for `ListView` and `GridView` it doesn't matter in both views the `getView`, `getItemCount`, `getTypeCount` is used so it's the same.
`RecyclerView` isn't needed if `ListView` with `ListAdapter` or `GridView` with grid adapters is already working for you.
If you have implemented correctly the `ViewHolder` pattern in your listviews then you won't see any big improvement over `RecycleView`.

Answer (score 3):

I worked a little with `RecyclerView` and still prefer `ListView`.

1. Sure, both of them use `ViewHolders`, so this is not an advantage.
2. A `RecyclerView` is more difficult in coding.
3. A `RecyclerView` doesn't contain a header and footer, so it's a minus.
4. A `ListView` doesn't require to make a ViewHolder. In cases where you want to have a list with sections or subheaders it would be a good idea to make independent items (without a ViewHolder), it's easier and doesn't require separate classes.

Comment: you can make header and content side in recyclerview adapter and it will be more flexible than listview. just hard to change ur mind listview to recyclerview but if you can do this,you will understand what i mean.listview deprecated just go try to learn recyclerview goodluck

Comment: @erginduran, I used both. ListView is still widely used and is not deprecated. Also it wastes less memory than RecyclerView. If you want only to replace a ListView with RecyclerView, it won't be a good idea.

Comment: just check why this guys developed recyclerview for? its improvement of listview, right? there are many old libs and apps in google play so you are right listview is still widely used.just leave old things in the past. check comparisons -> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525112/android-recyclerview-vs-listview-with-viewholder)

Comment: @erginduran, thanks. You are right, RecyclerView has some advantages. My answer was about usual tasks in where a ListView is sometimes more easier than a RecyclerView. Of course, animation and some other improvements are difficult or not possible in a ListView.

Comment: I added some aspects in that topic, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39721769/2914140.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: You should use RecyclerView in a situation where you want to show a lot of items, and the number of them is dynamic. ListView should only be used when the number of items is always the same and is limited to the screen size.

You find it harder because you are thinking just with the Android library in mind.

Today there exists a lot of options that help you build your own adapters, making it easy to build lists and grids of dynamic items that you can pick, reorder, use animation, dividers, add footers, headers, etc, etc.

Don't get scared and give a try to RecyclerView, you can starting to love it making a list of 100 items downloaded from the web (like facebook news) in a ListView and a RecyclerView, you will see the difference in the UX (user experience) when you try to scroll, probably the test app will stop before you can even do it.

I recommend you to check this two libraries for making easy adapters:

[FastAdapter by mikepenz](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter)

[FlexibleAdapter by davideas](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter)

Comment: I think your statements about the performance difference between the two are exaggerated. I've been using ListView in a production app since 2012, displaying up to 3000 items with ~10 different Views in each row, absolutely no problems performance wise even on old Android 2.3 devices.

Answer (score 2):

There are many differences between ListView and RecyclerView, but you should be aware of the following in particular:

- The ViewHolder pattern is entirely optional in ListView, but it’s baked into RecyclerView.
- ListView only supports vertical scrolling, but RecyclerView isn’t limited to vertically scrolling lists.

Answer (score 2):

I want just emphasize that RecyclerView is a part of the compatibility package. It means that instead of using the feature and code from OS, every application carries own RecyclerView implementation. Potentially, a feature similar to RecyclerView can be a part of a future OS and using it from there can be beneficial. For example Harmony OS will be out soon.The compatibility package license can be changed in the future and it can be an implication. Summery of disadvantages:

1. licensing
2. a bigger foot print especially as a part of many apps
3. losing in efficiency if some feature coming from OS can be there

But on a good note, an implementation of some functionality, as swiping items, is coming from RecyclerView.

All said above has to be taken in a consideration.