# What is difference between ListView and RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-recyclerview

I wanted to make fast Responsive Adapter.

Which view is more efficient, `ListView` or `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for both prior to asking this question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recycler View VS List View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recycler-view-vs-list-view)

Answer (score 3):

Basically It depends on your implementation. RecyclerView is the new widget that has different architecture principles. If your list is simple and wouldn't use Choice modes, Selection mode and other hard dependent things like CursorAdapter, then it is faster and better to use RecyclerView - it would have better performance. In other case it is better to use ListView - you have all things like SelectionMode out of the box.

Comment: Ironically if your list is overly complex, i.e. arbitrary layouts, then you have to use RecyclerView too.

Comment: If the list item is heavy, you better use custom view to avoid too many 'layouts', 'measurements' and 'drawings' :)

Comment: I meant arbitrarily sized and laid out cells, like a programming guide: http://img.hexus.net/v2/lifestyle/reviews/apple/macmini/eyetv_program_guide_c.jpg