# ListView, RecyclerView or ..?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-recyclerview

I have to create a list of posts like facebook, so there is a white box centered with margins and inside the picture with the name and after the post content.

Now, my question is: What's the best way to do this? ListView, RecyclerView with custom layout or what?

Thank you.

Comment: Probably this post can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RecyclerView` with [CardView](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html). This is the best because:

1. Performance - The RecyclerView has good performance
2. UI - `CardView` will give you the look & feel you need

I suggest to walk through the attached link of implementing `CardView`. Note that this is also the newest solution in Android.