# Best way to make a layout with many buttons on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

First I have build a simple android application which had only five optios to select. For this purpose I used five Buttons on main Activity. Now I have more than twenty buttons in a ScrollView to select. What is the best way to represent  this kind of application (using buttons in a ScrollView? using TabHost? or with some other widget?)

The app look like this now:

[image]

Comment: Have you check out a `ListView` o the new `RecyclerView`?

Comment: use `RecyclerView`

Comment: Yeah, I'd use a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView vs. ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview)

Comment: Grid view and List view will be good

Answer (score 2):

`Grid View` or `List View` or `Recycler View`

the Adapter automatically will add buttons with the names you want, something that I did for my upcoming app.
I made a java class called `data` which has 'data` for my app.
it has an array of images for my GridView.

**SO:**

- Make a class called data
- Add a `public final static String[] myArray` array of your names, or data
- Now, whenever you want to access them, use data.myArray
- If you want to access one item ,use data.myArray[itemIndex]
- Don't forget, indexes are zero based, not 1
- Put your button inside a `viewHolder` class
- find the id of the button in the `getView` if `convertView` is `null` & set the holder as a tag

NOTE : after finding the ID of the button, just leave it don't do anything or edit the text, continue reading please.

- Use that array with your custom adapter
  as

`gridView.setAdapter(new myCustomAdapter(parameter1, parameter2,data.myArray);`

use [this](https://github.com/LeOndaz/ButtonZat) , I just made it yesterday, added array of buttons feature now. You can just learn it or use it or commit changes.

NOTE :

- You can make an array of listeners just like any primitive data type, `View.OnClickListener[]` and name it, initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grid view`. it will be easy to show multiple buttons on screen using grid view.