# how to show data in list-view (recyclerview is better)?

Tags: android, tablelayout

I want to show some data from  `string.xml` of `string-array` in this kind of table

Below is the table image I am looking for:

[image]

I have to make `custom adapter` but I don't know how

Below is the code for my custom `listview`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_string"
    tools:text="asifgiouweifhsklajfhkh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/quantityView"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="??" />

<TextView
    android:text="QO"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/list_item_string"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/delete_btn"
    android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/unitView"/>

<TextView
    android:text="1234"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/quantityView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/unitView"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/unitView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

How to do it? Thank You

Comment: you can use listview and recyclerview for that. just create layout for every row.

Comment: the xml code above is layout for every row. it has multi columns. i did some research that i have to make a custom adapter but i dont know how to do that.

Comment: i post custom adapter code

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/28886129/3789993 and this http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapter for Listview:

```
public class TalktimeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PlanDetails> {


    Context context;
    View view;


    public TalktimeAdapter(Context context,List<PlanDetails> items) {
        super(context,0, items);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        PlanDetails rowitem= getItem(position);
        view=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (view==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fulltalk_items,parent,false);
            holder=new ViewHolder();

            holder.planoverview=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.planoverview);
            holder.planbenefit=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.planbenefit);
            holder.planamount=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.planamount);
            view.setTag(holder);

        }else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }

        assert rowitem != null;
        holder.planoverview.setText(rowitem.getOne());
        holder.planbenefit.setText(rowitem.getTwo());
        holder.planamount.setText(rowitem.getThree());


        return view;

    }
    private static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView planoverview,planbenefit,planamount;
    }
}
```

Model class:

```
public class PlanDetails  {

    String one,two,three;


    public PlanDetails(String one, String two, String three) {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
        this.three = three;
    }


    public String getThree() {
        return three;
    }

    public void setThree(String three) {
        this.three = three;
    }

    public String getTwo() {
        return two;
    }

    public void setTwo(String two) {
        this.two = two;
    }

    public String getOne() {
        return one;
    }

    public void setOne(String one) {
        this.one = one;
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
public class FullTalkTimeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    TalktimeAdapter adapter;
    List<PlanDetails> row;

      @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fulltalk_view);

        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.planList);

        row = new ArrayList<>();
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","11"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","12"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","13"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","14"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","15"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","16"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","17"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","18"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","19"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","21"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","31"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","41"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","51"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","61"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","71"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","81"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","91"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","101"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","121"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","1011"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","1521"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","1081"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","1291"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","1001"));
        row.add(new PlanDetails("oneoneone","twotwotwo","1261"));


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
               PlanDetails pm= row.get(i);
                    Toast.makeText(FullTalkTimeActivity.this,pm.getThree().trim(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
        adapter = new TalktimeAdapter(getActivity(), row);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

}
```

Comment: how to start a chat ?

Comment: write some comments and chat option pop ups