# Loading data dynamically in list view

Tags: android, listview

which class is need to  be implemented for loading data from cloud storage as per visible list items and how to add indeterminate progress bar while loading below  listview?(example:listview in google play store)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: How the data is loaded has nothing to do with where or how it will be shown in the UI.

To answer your question: The Play Store uses nested instances of `RecyclerView`. On launching it, a `ProgressBar` with `indeterminate="true"` is shown as overlay while data is fetched in background.
If a particular list needs to fetch more items, an item containing a `ProgressBar` with `indeterminate=true` is appended as item at the end of the list and replaced once more content is available.

To load data in the background there are many ways:
Have a look here to get started:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

To actually display data see:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: thanks for hint but i have 5 months of experience (starter) its too much for me.

Comment: okay no problem, maybe clarify what you need then so i can help. :)

Comment: will u please help if i don't get to the code afterwards.

Comment: i can try, although i am not sure what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use Recyclerview instead of list view, as per recommendations.
For reading further about recyclerview follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview).

If you want to load image dynamically I recommend you to go with Glide library.

To learn more about Glide, follow link: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

For loading data for list view you have to get data in the form of json, for handling network requests use Retrofit and study from this [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiryoSKz5LSAhVJQ48KHSUjD_oQFgghMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffuturestud.io%2Fblog%2Fretrofit-getting-started-and-android-client&usg=AFQjCNHTZmL6T5xuVsAc_eW7SZf2J9ayVA&sig2=z9QA972C3dtMY3lVBu9fzA).

For making progressbar indeterminant just add indeterminant attribute to progressbar view in xml.

I hope this will solve your problem !!!