# RecyclerView vs ListView for a chat application

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, chat

Which is better to use to display chat messages? As far as I understand, RecyclerView supports more custom view orientations (and is generally seen to be superior performance-wise), but since chat is inherently list-like, would it be better to use ListView?

Does it make much of a difference either way for this use-case?

Thanks!

Comment: RecyclerView is better for chat application.

Comment: RecyclerView performs better than a ListView

Comment: Since chat log is potentially unlimited, better use `RecyclerView` for memory and performance.

Comment: check this one... http://stackoverflow.com/a/28886129/5614644

Comment: read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview/29078116#29078116

Answer (score 0):

Yup,Recyclerview is good option.

Answer (score 0):

Recyclerview is a better option becoz Recyclerview has own holder class and Recyclerview has many in build animation. It easy to use and more light weight then listview. [You can find recyclerview example here](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)

Answer (score 0):

Recycler View is better option as one can use View Holder to avoid the issues faced during scrolling.

Also there are more advantages of recycler view over List view