# How to add dynamically item in ListView with conditional cell type?

Tags: android, listview

I try to add dynamic number of cell inside listview using custom cell layout and ArrayAdapter and it done well. But i face a problem when i want each cell may different follow type of data.

Example i have 3 categories inside a listview :

1. Video (video_custom_cell.xml)
2. Photo (photo_custom_cell.xml)
3. Audio (audio_custom_cell.xml)

if data is video then i use cell number one, else if data is photo i use photo_custom_cell and else i use audio_custom_cell.

What i have tried only can reuse a custom cell for dynamic number of row, but i still not find how to use custom cell follow by type of data inside cell.

Can anyone help me to explain an example for my problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to use RecyclerView instead of ListView, you will be able to do these type of thing.
You can learn how to use RecyclerView on this link:
[link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)
To resolve your problem, with recyclerview, you just have to follow the first answer:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

It's more complicated than listView, but it's more powerfull.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom adapter for this and inside the `getView` function you do for example:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        if(items.get(position).type.equals("video")) {
            rowView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.video_custom_cell, null);
        }else if(items.get(position).type.equals("photo")) {
            rowView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.photo_custom_cell, null);
        }
    } else {
        rowView = convertView;
    }
}
```