# What is the difference between "Recycleview" and "Listview" on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

What is the difference between "Recycleview" and "Listview" on Android?

Exact meaning of Recycleview and Listview in Android.

Comment: I think this question has already been answered
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview

Answer (score 3):

`ListView` class is a bit too heavy – it has a lot of responsibilities. Whenever we have to handle the list, such as to configure it in some way, the only way to do this is through the `ListView` object or inside the adapter.

A lot of things that we hate in the ListView were fixed or changed in the `RecyclerView`. It’s more efficient by default, the layout is separated and we have more possibilities over the data set inside the adapter.

These are the crucial differences between `ListView` and `RecyclerView`:

## 1 ViewHolder

The `ViewHolder` pattern allows us to make our list scrolling act smoothly. It stores list row views references and, thanks to this, calling the `findViewById()` method only occurs a couple of times, rather than for the entire dataset and on each `bind view`.

The `RecyclerView`’s adapter forces us to use the `ViewHolder` pattern. The creating part (inflating the layout and finding views) and updating the views is split into two methods — `onCreateViewHolder()` and `onBindViewHolder()`.

The `ListView`, on the other hand, doesn’t give us that kind of protection by default, so without implementing the `ViewHolder` pattern inside the `getView()` method, we’ll end with inefficient scrolling in our list.

## 2 LayoutManager

The `LayoutManager` takes responsibility for layouting row views. Thanks to this, `RecyclerView` doesn’t have to think about how to position the row view. This class gives us the opportunity to choose the way that we want to show the row views and how to scroll the list. For example, if we want to scroll our list vertically or horizontally, we can choose `LinearLayoutManager`. For grids, it is more suitable to choose the `GridLayoutManager`.

Previously, with the use of the ListView, we were only able to create a ***vertical-scrolling*** list, so it wasn’t that flexible. If we wanted grids on our list, we had to choose the other widget for that — `GridView`.

## 3 `ItemDecoration`

A duty of the `ItemDecoration` is simple in theory – add some decorations for the list row views – but in practice, it’s that simple to implement if we want to create a custom one. In this case, we should extend the `ItemDecoration` class and implement our solution. For example, the `RecyclerView` list has no dividers between rows by default and it’s consistent with the Material Design guidelines. However, if we want to add a divider for some reason, we can use
[DividerItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration.html) and add it to the `RecyclerView`.
In case we use the ListView, we have to figure out rows decorations by ourselves. There is no helper class like `ItemDecoration` for this widget.

## 4 ItemAnimator

The last but not least component of `RecyclerView` that I want to mention is `ItemAnimator`. As we can expect, it’s handling row views animations like list appearance and disappearance, adding or removing particular views and so on. By default, `RecyclerView`’s list animations are nice and smooth. Of course, we can change that by creating our own `ItemAnimator`, which is also not that easy. To make it easier, we should extend the [SimpleItemAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SimpleItemAnimator.html) class and implement the methods that we need (just add animations to a ViewHolder’s views).
To be honest, implementing animations on the ListView was a pain. Again, we had to figure out how we want to handle them.

## 5 Notifying adapter

We have a couple of cool notifiers on the `RecyclerView`’s adapter. We are still able to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` but there are also ones for particular list elements, like `notifyItemInserted()`, `notifyItemRemoved()` or even `notifyItemChanged()` and more. We should use the most appropriate ones for what is actually happening, so the proper animations will fire correctly.

Using `ListView`, we were able to use just `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter and then had to handle the rest ourselves, again.