# android: Fragment for RecycleView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I read about ListView and RecycleView. I understood that RecycleView is a more advanced and flexible version of ListView. So like *ListFragment for listView*, Is there any inbuilt fragment for RecyleView? If i need a RecycleView inside a fragment then what is the proper way to implement it?

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/samples/RecyclerView/src/com.example.android.recyclerview/RecyclerViewFragment.html

Comment: isn't that a custom fragment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any inbuilt fragment for RecyleView?

No. there isn't one.

Unlike `ListFragment` for `listview`, there isn't any default implementation provided for `RecyclerView`. And `RecyclerView` is available through the `support-v7` library and it's not bundled with the Android source.

For difference between `RecyclerView` and `ListView` check this:

[Recyclerview vs ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview)

Here are some good resources you will like to read:

[Creating Lists and Cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

[Using the RecyclerView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView)

And an example:

[RecyclerViewFragment](https://developer.android.com/samples/RecyclerView/src/com.example.android.recyclerview/RecyclerViewFragment.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out these tutorials

[Using the recycler view](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview)

[Multiple views in recycler view](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView)