# What view should I use to store songs for a music player? A ListView or RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

Ok so i am trying to make a music app and i watched a tutorial saying that i should use a ListView but that video came out in 2015. A collegue told me that a recyclerView would be better

Comment: Why not both? You can code both views

Comment: which one of the views would make the coding easier?

Comment: Instead of trying to make the coding easier, perhaps you should look at it from a User Experience perspective("which makes my app better to use")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for simplicity, then I suggest ListView. It has detailed documentation (which can be found at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html).
It also has easy-to-use setAdapter functions to help you enter your data.

On the other hand, RecyclerView is more complex. It is more powerful and allows you to perform more tasks (such as various layout patterns, described at https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html), but its API is more technical than that of ListView's.

If you are just going for displaying a list of songs and possibly subtitles, then I suggest going with the more simple route - ListView.

Answer (score 1):

It is better. `RecyclerView` is a `ListView` improvement! If you want to know more you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview). Basically it reuses views, delegates common animations. You can also put items in a grid/staggered/linear/whatever layout through `LayoutManager`.

Comment: but does it make it easier to use ?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I strongly encourage you to use it. Trust me, it's the correct thing to do.

Comment: ok right i did use the recyclerview does this mean i have to use different code compared to the listview

Comment: Yes, the setup is a bit different. Follow the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: the rule of thumb is to use always RecyclerView instead of ListView.