# Android - Handling images that are part of solution and images that are downloaded

Tags: android, image-caching

I am unclear how images are handled in Android in terms of caching.

Let's say, I have an app
that is 3 levels deep (so, it has 3 Activities that are pushed on top of
each other).

If each of my 3 activities shows 3 images in the ToolBar of all 3 Activities, my understanding is that the same 3 images are going to be loaded in memory 3 times.  This is resulting in 9 images taking memory although it is really only 3 images, they are just
loaded multiple times.

Also, let's say my main activity has a ListView showing information about documents retrieved over the network.

Each list view item is customized to show 3 pieces of information:

- an image representing a type of document (i.e. .txt, .pdf, .docx, .js, ...)
- a string representing a title
- a string representing some description

If the above ListView loads million items (each represents a document) and assume all are a word document, then all million images for .docx type are downloaded but it really is just one image that I need.  This seem to be obvious waste of network bandwidth and memory, I'd like to download only one image and use it million times rather than download million images and use them each only once.

So, in scenario like this, where I dont know what kind of image I will need and therefore do not have it in image assets but rely on downloaded image to show document type, is there some kind of caching strategy that I could use to avoid having to download same image million times?

Is it provided by Android already?

**UPDATE**

In my above example of Toolbar images, these are Android Resource images (so, drawables).  So, for these, I believe these are cached by default?

However, the ListView images are images that are downloaded from the web, so in my example above with custom ListViewItem consisting of 3 Views (one Image and 2 Labels), the Image would be downloaded at the same time ListView is being rendered.  I am providing a simple ListView item with only 3 Views but it could be 10 views (say 4 images and 6 Labels).  The main point is that the one image is downloaded from the web during the rendering process of the ListView.  Since that image might be repeating, how to awoid downloading same image but to use cached one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First about Lists of items**

`ListView` does not work in such an inefficient way you assume. But if you really care about efficiency and handling really large lists of data it is advised to use `RecyclerView`. There is a good discussion and an answer with the comparison of both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28886129/1824898).

If you plan to handle a list of thousands of docs with certain limited collection of document type icons the best practice would be to have a HashMap of Bitmaps, which you will link to the particular list item (regardless of what you will pick to use: `RecyclerView` or `ListView`).

Here is a brief example (it is not correct java, just to give an idea) with ListViews' adapter class:

```
public class DocumentsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final HashMap<String, Bitmap> docIcons = HashMap<String, Bitmap>()
    private final Activity mContext;
    private final List<String> mItems;

    public DocumentsListAdapter(Activity context, List<String> items) {
         docIcons.put("docx", loadDocBitmapFromDisk());
         docIcons.put("xls", loadXlsBitmapFromDisk());
         docIcons.put("pdf", loadPdfBitmapFromDisk());
         // and so on...
         mItems = items;
         mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);

        txtTitle.setText(mItems.get(position));

        if(items.get(position).endsWith(".docx")) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(docIcons.get("docx"))

        } // and so on for other types...
    }
}
```

This example does not cover how you obtain your icons. You can download them from internet, store them on disk and when application needs those icons — you load them from disk as bitmaps and store in the memory only one time each bitmap and reuse them in the views. Implementing this logic along with RecyclerView you will get you rather efficient application which doesn't waste memory and is very responsive.

You don't have to store `HashMap` with bitmaps in adapter but it is good option if you use it only in one place. If you need to use it in different activities, then consider to keep this `HashMap` somewhere else, where it won't be reloaded every time user switches between different activities utilizing similar `ListViews`.

**Handling multiple Activities with the same images**

Concerning the Activities it depends how do you store your images. If they are also get downloaded from the Internet and cached on disk you may do the same as described in the ListView section of this answer. Just keep somewhere list of images that you had loaded into the memory and use

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(someBitmap)
```

when you need to display it in the specific part of activity.

In the case you are working with application resources it is even easier, as you can do something like this:

```
Drawable dr = context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.my_favourite_image);
imageView.setImageDrawable(dr);
```

All work with memory efficient usage is done here under the hoods.

**How to avoid downloading same image but to use cached one**

It depends on how you are going to track the uniqueness of each image. E.g. if each image has unique URL the most basic solution is to use the HashMap with the URL of an image as the key.

More complicated but more flexible and correct decision would be to use something like [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) caching tools. This is not android specific and very broad topic to cover in this answer, but you can [take a look here](http://www.baeldung.com/guava-cache).

Although, if you plan to mess with complex layouts of images and care about performance, check `Anko` and [this benchmark](https://android.jlelse.eu/400-faster-layouts-with-anko-da17f32c45dd). This is not related to content caching, but layout rendering performance can be improved by 3 times and more.

Comment: Thanks Klaus, but would you mind taking look at the UPDATE section I added.  I'd just like to clarify what I mean.  Much appreciated

Comment: @pixel I updated the answer. As I had said caching logic depends greatly on what options do you have to identify unique cache parts and how you keep your cache up to date. That's the key. Without this information it is hard to make optimal decision.

Comment: Thanks Klaus, I think I understand now thanks to your great explanations.  In my case, uniqueness could be determined by the extension of document in this case (i.e. docx, .pdf, .txt, .js, ...) and that cache would never expire since a document will never change its type I guess.  Also, I would not download images first and save them to the disk, then load them in a list.  I am ready to accept your answer, just let me know if you have to add something based on this comment.  Much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand you correctly now. If I got you wrong please tell me. As far as I understand you are going to cache links: each unique file — file type icon. Don't do this: operation of detection of document type is very cheap. All you really need is to have a bitmap of each unique image in the memory. And the image must be already prepared for the size it is going to be rendered: it should not be bigger or smaller, than `ImageView` that will render it.

Comment: About 2 years ago in similar task where we had to render a really big list of products in a RecyclerView, while each product could have an image, representing that product in 2 resolutions. Images were originating from backend server, so we had to download them, then save on disk, resize and only after that — render each. The best performance we had when we prepared images beforehand, than cached prepared images on disk and part of them in memory. It didn't lag even on very cheap android devices with single core CPUs.

Comment: OK, let me clarify, when you say prepared images beforehand, you are talking about having images as part of drawable (or mipmaps) directories.  These images are cached and in memory when app runs.  Correct?

Comment: I mean that if you download images from internet, they may have different resolution, than you need. Like you download 200x200px icon and your `ImageView` has 48x48dp. To display it effectively (without resizes) you will have to prepare a bitmap with the same device-specific pixel size, which will vary . That's what I mean by preparing images beforehand.