# How do I fill a ListView with a specific value?

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, adapter

I have a `ListView` that is populated with values from the `mySQL` database, and not all values are pulled, but those that match the specified condition: `if (getHarakterByid (currCount) .equals ("Sale of monitors"))`. At the moment, in the listview element, one line together displays the position, code and address values, and only one address needs to be displayed. How can I do it? Tried `SimpleAdapter`, but nothing comes out.

MainActivity.java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button start;
    private Intent districts;
    private Intent detail;

    private static RequestQueue mQueue;
    private static ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private static ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, Object>> adapter;
    private static ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, Object>> sAdapter;

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> d_Task;
    private static final String it_address = "Address"; // Верхний текст
    private static final String it_id = "Position"; // ниже главного
    private static final String it_kz = "Kod";

    private static Context context;

    private static Handler handler;

    public static ListView LISTVIEW;
    public static final Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<String, String>(1);

    private static final int delay_min = 30 * 1000 * 60;

    private Integer verCode;
    private String verName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LISTVIEW = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LIST_VIEW);
        LISTVIEW.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        String[] from = {};
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, Object>>(this, R.layout.main_item,
                R.id.main_textitem);
        LISTVIEW.setAdapter(adapter);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        detail = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
        districts = new Intent(context, DistrictsActivity.class);
        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        try {
            verCode = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
            verName = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        fields.put("ROOT", context.getString(R.string.DATA));
        fields.put("data_unp_err",
                context.getString(R.string.data_unpack_error));
        fields.put("ver_remind", context.getString(R.string.ver_remind_text));

        DataStruct.getStruct().setPrefObj(getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE));
        DataStruct.getStruct().getPrefObj()
                .setCurrVersionInfo(verName, verCode);

        DataStruct.getStruct().setRequestQueue(mQueue);
        DataStruct.getStruct().setMAdapter(adapter);
        DataStruct.getStruct().setAdapter((new DBadapter(context, verCode)));

        if (!DataStruct.getStruct().getPrefObj().checkVersionInfo()
                || !DataStruct.getStruct().getPrefObj().checkAccDataExists()) {
            Intent accountActivity = new Intent(context,
                    CreateAccountActivity.class);
            startActivity(accountActivity);
        }

        DataStruct.getStruct().getSavedRecords();
        startActionOnTimer();

        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (checkNetWorkState()) {
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
                    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

                    handler = new Handler() {
                        @Override
                        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                            switch (message.what) {
                                case WaitResponce.statusNumKeys.RESPONSE_FAILED:
                                    stopMFDialog(String.valueOf(message.obj));
                                    DataStruct.getStruct().getRequestObject()
                                            .cancelQueue();
                                    break;
                                case WaitResponce.statusNumKeys.RESPONSE_WAITING:
                                    progressDialog.setMessage("Подождите...");
                                    progressDialog.show();
                                    break;
                                case WaitResponce.statusNumKeys.RESPONSE_OK:
                                    stopMFDialog(String.valueOf(message.obj));
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    if (DataStruct.getStruct().getListener()
                            .setHandler(handler)) {
                        DataStruct.getStruct().getReqParams()
                                .prepareParamForSelectReq();
                        DataStruct.getStruct().getListener().getEvent()
                                .onResponceStartWait();
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        LISTVIEW.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                HashMap<String, Object> itemHashMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String titleItem = itemHashMap.get(it_id).toString();
                int a = Integer.parseInt(titleItem);
                detail.putExtra("arg", a);
                startActivity(detail);
            }
        });
    }


    private void showMessageDialog() {
        String Doz = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < DataStruct.getStruct().getMainListSize(); i++) {
            String Kod1 = DataStruct.getStruct().getKodByid(i);
            String Sut1 = DataStruct.getStruct().getSutByid(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < OldDataStruct.getStruct().getMainListSize(); j++) {
                String Kod2 = OldDataStruct.getStruct().getKodByid(j);
                String Sut2 = OldDataStruct.getStruct().getSutByid(j);
                if (Kod1.equals(Kod2)) {
                    if (Sut1.equals(Sut2)) {
                    } else {
                        Doz = Sut1.replaceFirst(Sut2, "");
                        String Address = DataStruct.getStruct().getAddressByid(i);
                        Address = Address.replace("city", "");
                        Address = Address.replace("street", "st.");
                        AlertDialog.Builder quitDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        quitDialog.setTitle(Address);
                        quitDialog.setMessage("Addition: " + Doz);
                        quitDialog.setNegativeButton("ОК",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        return;
                                    }
                                });
                        quitDialog.show();
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }

    private void startActionOnTimer() {
        Intent l_intent = new Intent(this, UpdateOnTimer.class);
        PendingIntent l_pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                l_intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis(), delay_min, l_pendingIntent);
    }

    public static void stopMFDialog(String message) {
        if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        ShowMessage.Show(message);
    }

    public static void setViewAdapter(ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, Object>> mAdapter) {
        adapter = mAdapter;
        LISTVIEW.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

DataStruct.java code:

```
public class DataStruct extends Application {

    /**
     * здесь собраны все функции для операции с массивом данных (заявок)
     */

    private static DataStruct mStruct;

    private RequestParams params;
    private Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> mainDataList;
    private DistrictDataAdapterStruct districtsList;
    private Integer currCount;
    private Integer currIndex;
    private Pref pref;
    private AddRequest request;
    private String districtName;
    private DBadapter dbAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, Object>> mAdapter;
    private TasksFieldsNames fieldsNames;
    private WaitResponce waitResponce;

    private void setMainDataList(Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> list) {
        mainDataList = list;
    }

    private ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, Object>> getMainAdapter() {
        return mAdapter;
    }

    public void setMAdapter(ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, Object>> _mAdapter) {
        mAdapter = _mAdapter;
    }

    public int getMainListSize() {
        return mainDataList.size();
    }

    public Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> getMainDataList() {
        return mainDataList;
    }
    public void setAdapter(DBadapter dbAdapter) {
        this.dbAdapter = dbAdapter;
    }

    public void setCurrIndex(Integer i) {
        currIndex = i;
    }

    public final DBadapter getAdapter() {
        return dbAdapter;
    }

    public DistrictDataAdapterStruct getDistricstsList() {
        return districtsList;
    }

    public WaitResponce getListener() {
        return waitResponce;
    }

    @SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays")
    public void getSavedRecords() {
        Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> LIST = new HashMap<Integer, Map<String, String>>();
        LIST = getAdapter().getSelectedRows();
        if (LIST != null) {
            setRecFromBase(LIST);
        }
    }

    public Map<String, String> getRecById(Integer i) {
        return mainDataList.get(i);
    }

    public String getAddressByid(Integer i) {
        return mainDataList.get(i).get("Address").trim();
    }

    public String getSutByid(Integer i) {
        return mainDataList.get(i).get("The essence of the application").trim();
    }

    public String getKodByid(Integer i) {
        return mainDataList.get(i).get("Claim code").trim();
    }

    public String getHarakterByid(Integer i) {
        return mainDataList.get(i).get("Nature of the application").trim();
    }

    public void setRequestQueue(RequestQueue queue) {
        request = new AddRequest(queue);
    }

    public AddRequest getRequestObject() {
        return request;
    }

    public void setPrefObj(SharedPreferences preferences) {
        pref = new Pref(preferences);
    }

    public Pref getPrefObj() {
        return pref;
    }

    public RequestParams getReqParams() {
        return params;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllRec() {
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(0);
        Iterator<Map<String, String>> iterator = mainDataList.values().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            values.addAll(iterator.next().values());
        }
        return values;
    }


    public void createDistrictsList() {
        districtsList = new DistrictDataAdapterStruct();
    }

    public void setDistricts(ArrayList<Map<String, String>> items) {
        final String idRaion = "kodDistrict";
        final String valRaion = "District";
        final String KolvoZayavok = "QuantityApplications";
        createDistrictsList();
        Iterator<Map<String, String>> iterator = items.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map<String, String> item = iterator.next();
            getDistricstsList().addItem(String.valueOf(item.get(valRaion)),
                    Integer.parseInt(item.get(KolvoZayavok)),
                    Integer.parseInt(item.get(idRaion)));
        }
    }

    public void setRecFromBase(Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> LIST) {
        if (LIST.size() > 0) {
            setMainDataList(LIST);
            currCount = mainDataList.size();
            addItemsToMainAdapter();
        }
    }
    //добавление значений в ListView
    private void addItemsToMainAdapter() {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>(currCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < currCount; i++) {
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            hm.put("Address",getAddressByid(i));
            hm.put("Kod",getKodByid(i));
            hm.put("Position",""+i);
            items.add(hm);
        }
        mAdapter.addAll(items);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        MainActivity.setViewAdapter(getMainAdapter());
    }
    //обновление значений в ListView
    private void addItemToMainAdapter() {
        if (getHarakterByid(currCount).equals("Sale of monitors")) {
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            hm.put("Address",getAddressByid(currCount));
            hm.put("Kod",getKodByid(currCount));
            hm.put("Position",""+currCount);
            mAdapter.add(hm);
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        MainActivity.setViewAdapter(getMainAdapter());
    }

    public void setMainNode() {
        currCount = mainDataList.size();
        mainDataList.put(currCount, new LinkedHashMap<String, String>());
    }

    private void setChildNode(String key, String value) {
        mainDataList.get(currCount).put(key, value.trim());
    }

    public void setREC(JSONObject unParseRec) {
        setMainNode();
        Iterator<Names> iterator = getFieldsNamesList().getNamesList();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Names item = iterator.next();
            String val = unParseRec.optString(item.getUSName());

            setChildNode(item.getRUSName(),
                    (val.isEmpty()) ? getFieldsNamesList().emptyValue : val);
        }
        addItemToMainAdapter();

    }

    public TasksFieldsNames getFieldsNamesList() {
        return fieldsNames;
    }

    private DataStruct() {
        currCount = 0;
        districtName = null;
        params = new RequestParams();
        fieldsNames = new TasksFieldsNames();
        waitResponce = new WaitResponce();
        mainDataList = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Map<String, String>>(currCount);
    }

    public static synchronized DataStruct getStruct() {
        if (mStruct == null) {
            mStruct = new DataStruct();
        }
        return mStruct;
    }

    private void replaceItems() {
        if (currCount > 0) {
            Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Map<String, String>>(0);
            Integer index = 0;
            Iterator<Map<String, String>> items = mainDataList.values().iterator();
            do {
                Map<String, String> item = items.next();
                map.put(index, item);
                index++;
            } while (items.hasNext());
            mainDataList.clear();
            setMainDataList(map);
        }
    }

    public void deleteRec() {
        getMainAdapter().remove(getMainAdapter().getItem(currIndex));
        getMainAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        String task_code = getFieldsNamesList().getRUNameByTag(TasksFieldsNames.fields_name.task_code);
        getAdapter().deleteRows(getRecById(currIndex).get(task_code));
        mainDataList.remove(currIndex);
        currCount = mainDataList.size();
        replaceItems();
    }

    public void deleteAllRec() {
        getMainAdapter().clear();
        getMainAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        getAdapter().reCreateBase();
        mainDataList.clear();
        currCount = mainDataList.size();
    }

    public String getDistrictName() {
        return districtName;
    }

    public void setDistrictName(String districtName) {
        this.districtName = districtName;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use custom BaseAdapter and put your logic in getView(); method. Make your Basics clear first.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first , I recommend using RecyclerView instead of ListView. As to why , see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview).

See Google's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html#java) on how to create a proper list.

You will need write a custom adapter and put your logic in onBindViewHolder

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // your logic goes here
        holder.mTextView.setText("some filtered data");

    }
```