# Is it possible to bind all the views in recycleiew at once?

Tags: android-recyclerview

Since there is dependency for 1st view from second view, setInitialItemPrefetchCount() dosent work either

Answer (score 0):

`setInitialItemPrefetchCount()` is not what you think. It tells the system how many items to prefetch to fill the RecyclerView when it’s about to scroll on screen.

And It is for nested RecyclerViews. check [this article](https://medium.com/google-developers/recyclerview-prefetch-c2f269075710)

Beside this, you can not bind all views at once. And this is not bad. [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28886129/3360584) this also

Comment: Okay! So is it possible to bind  2 views at once when 1st view is visible and 2nd view is not?can we set any limit for binding items?