# Why use ListView if RecyclerView Exists

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I understand and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview/33491455) post about the differences between LV and RV.
This all makes sense.
I understand that RV can handle large datasets much better than LV.

Why isn't LV deprecated by now or at least mentioned that RV should be used for performance reasons?
I never used RecyclerView but is it so much more complicated that its worth having 2 views that do essentially the same thing? Or maybe there is another reason?

Comment: *`Why isn't LV deprecated by now`* We don't know only Google know about it.

Comment: You can ask this question to Sundar Pichai :D

Comment: I'll ask him next time I meet with him over coffee

Answer (score 0):

One reason might be because the LV has it's own onItemClickedListener whereas with RV you have to make your own.

One reason why RecyclerView is better is because it recycles, as the names suggests, automatically the views inside the list.

I've worked with both and definitely recommend RV.