# Poor performance in the Listview with Images

Tags: android, listview, android-image

I did a lot of research before opening this title, but somehow I didn't get the result I wanted. My Listview has accelerated, but it's not enough.

When I make the listview up and down, sometimes it slows down and there are little frosts.

Is this because the Listview only consists of pictures? But when I examine other applications, I see that there is no problem in them.

Would you please review?

This is my adapter code :

```
public class pop_Adapter extends BaseAdapter  {
    private LayoutInflater userInflater;
    private List<pop_User> userList;
    Activity aa;
    public pop_Adapter(Activity activity, List<pop_User> userList) {
        userInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        aa = activity;
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return userList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return userList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    class ViewYerTutucu{

        RelativeLayout rela1;
        LinearLayout activity_main,lin1;
        TextView indir;
        ImageView imageViewUserPicture;

        ViewYerTutucu(View v){
            activity_main = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
            indir = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.indirmeSayisi);
            imageViewUserPicture = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.resim);
            lin1 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.lin1);

            rela1 = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rela1);
            rela1.getLayoutParams().height = (int) ( (MainActivity.height / MainActivity.width) * MainActivity.width/2 );  //(int)MainActivity.width/2-36;
            indir.setTextSize(MainActivity.pxToDp((int)MainActivity.width/23));

        }

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View lineView = view;

        ViewYerTutucu tutucu=null;

        if (lineView == null) {
            lineView = userInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_pop, viewGroup, false);
            tutucu=new ViewYerTutucu(lineView);
            lineView.setTag(tutucu);
        }
        else{
            tutucu= (ViewYerTutucu) lineView.getTag();
        }

        final pop_User user = userList.get(i);

        tutucu.indir.setText(user.getIndirme());

        Glide.with(aa).load(user.getTags()).into(tutucu.imageViewUserPicture);

        final ViewYerTutucu finalTutucu = tutucu;
        tutucu.lin1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.hangiBolum = "pop-"+(i*2);
                fragoyunsifir.ResimDegistir(user.getTags());
                fragoyunsifir.paylas.setTag(user.getId());
                fragoyunsifir.indir.setTag(user.getTags());
                fragoyunsifir.button1.setTag(user.getResim());
                Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(aa, R.anim.fade_in_acilis);
                fragoyunsifir.activity_main.startAnimation(fadeOut);
                fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        fragoyunsifir.gorunurYap();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });



        tutucu.indir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(aa, finalTutucu.indir.getText()+" downloads", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        if(reachedEndOfList(i)) loadMoreData();

        return lineView;
    }




    private boolean reachedEndOfList(int position) {
        // can check if close or exactly at the end
        return position == getCount() - 1;
    }

    private void loadMoreData() {

        MainActivity.News();

    }
}
```

Sample picture loaded :https://source.unsplash.com/-hI5dX2ObAs/540x720

Comment: You should use recyclerview

Comment: Use recyclerview

Comment: Make use of either Picasso or Glide image loading library, and then if the images are small, as in thumbnail, load thumbnails rather and load full image on big preview.

Comment: @VolkanSahin45 , i tried but same result :(

Comment: Unsplash has very high definition images. This can cause problems in your scrolling as well

Comment: @Janwilx72 i think, the cause of the problem is  not in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best for you to use a RecyclerView for smooth scrolling and performance. Have a look at this [guide](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-RecyclerView) to implement it in your app. Also consider using an image loading library like [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). This is because unsplash has high resolution images, which take time to download. However, an image loader library allows you to cache and compress images so that they can load quickly into your views.

Comment: already i have glide.. also i tried recylerview but result didn't change.

Comment: Are you populating your List with data from network requests made to the unsplash api?

Comment: Oh okay, and how are making those requests and how are you parsing them?

Comment: I send link to the adapter from activity and load it with glide.

Comment: Alright, so you're not using a networking library to make requests and a JSON parsing library?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i will see.. but do you have any opinion for this subject ? listview not very fast..

Comment: True, RecyclerView is faster than ListView, please have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview)

Answer (score 0):

For smooth scrolling and performance add Recyclerview inside ScrollView and set

```
 android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

This will load all content inside your recyclerview.. otherwise it will only load when you scroll down. This is what i think.
And also set

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
   }
```

inside your recyclerview adapter.
 It is to prevent position of the image that will change if you further scroll down and got to top.