# How to create a listView that draws from the bottom of the activity?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, drawerlayout

I'm creating an app and I want to draw my listView from the bottom, or a similar object to be drawn from the bottom and being able to select from its options.

I've tried setting Y position, defining layoutParams at listView setup, using layout gravity GravityCompact.START|Gravity.BOTTOM, stackFromBottom="true", I even tried pre setting up my listView but because I use the listView for different adapters with different amount of items it mostly start from somewhere in the center of the view.

I expect to manage to draw my listView from the bottom when it is aligned to the bottom, or even using a different option of android to draw a view from the bottom containing few clickable items.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to open listview from bottom to top?

Comment: @NileshPanchal From the bottom to a certain point on screen, I don't want it to cover the whole view.

Comment: For that, you need to implement bottom sheet view and inside bottom sheet load recycler view with your desired data and maintain your view with a callback listener if you want some actions in the recycler view.

Comment: @NileshPanchal Why RecyclerView and not ListView? What difference does it make? with dewbamb's answer I've used ListView inside a bottom sheet and drawn it from the bottom. The only thing I'm not sure yet is how it will work when I will change the adapter to another adapter with less or more items. usually that's when the ordinary ListView gets corrupted

Comment: Here you can find a difference  -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much I understand your question. You need to implement a bottom sheet. Which can be drawn out from bottom and can contain a list view.
There are two types of bottom sheet modal and persistent to know more follow this [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/).

This is the code which you need to write to implement bottom sheet in your app.

create a java file called BottomSheet and a layout file called bottom_sheet.xml.

java file will look like this.

```
public class BottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

AdapterMessage adapterMessage;
ArrayList<MessageModel> messageList;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, container, false);

    return view;
}
}
```

And then Implement your listView in this file and layout.

To call the bottom sheet you can use the following command.

```
BottomSheet bottomSheet = new BottomSheet();
bottomSheet.show((getSupportFragmentManager() ,"bottom sheet message");
```

For some proper tutorial on how to use [bottom sheet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfpRL2K1hJk&t=418s)

Comment: Thanks!! Finally something that worked. By using both links I've managed to do what I intended.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need an inverted list in your listview. To do that, do this in your adapter:

```
String item = getItem(getCount()-position-1);
```

Comment: Where exactly? I am Implementing ListAdapter in my listView adapter. Do I need to use something else?

Comment: Inside your adapter getView method