# What to use instead of RecyclerView if not recycling items

Tags: android

I am a beginner and I have seen many tutorials on how to create a list using `RecyclerView`, but I can't find any how to use a list without recycling. I have a list of 3 items. what type of view should I use if I don't want to recycle?

Comment: you can use [listview](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm) insted of recycle view.

Comment: ListView was the original View provided for list item screen. For memory management point of view ListView with ViewHolder pattern was used but it had its own drawback. Finally Google came up with RecyclerView. As per my understanding irrespective of list size you should use RecyclerView. First you need to understand when will recycling help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to look at you list would be as simple items (since there are only 3). You can just add items to a `LinearLayout` with orientation as `vertical`.

You can even go further and create a common item layout XML, and using a for loop, inflate your `LinearLayout`. Example:

```
//create item class
@AllArgsConstructor @Getter
private static class Item {
    private int iconId;
    private String mainText;
    private String detailsText;
}

// create item
private Item ITEM_1 = new Item(R.drawable.some_drawable, getString(R.string.some_string), getString(R.string.some_string));

//add item to an arrayList (only add what you want that logged in user to see :D)
itemList.add((ITEM_1))

//layout you want to add to
@BindView(R.id.content) LinearLayout layoutToAddTo;

LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
for (Item item : itemList) {  // a list which holds all your Items
    //XML that the Item class matches.
    View card = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card, layoutToAddTo, false);
    bindContent(card, item);
    card.setOnClickListener(__ -> /* set your listener */));
    layoutToAddTo.addView(card);
}

//bind your content
private void bindContent(View view, Item item) {
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_icon)).setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, item.getIconId());
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_main_text)).setText(item.getMainText());
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_details_text)).setText(item.getDetailsText());
}
```

Best for few items, otherwise try to use **Recycler View**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ListView` if you don't want to recycle the list item.
Here [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView)

Comment: But this question say ListView also recycler? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works

Comment: have a look on it [LRecyclerView vs. ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview)

Comment: If you have fixed three items & items will not increase in your app any time,  then batter not to use any List type instead use import  ```xml``` three times you import design ```xml``` file in your main ```xml```