# Why does Recycler View offers a better experience than List View?

Tags: android, kotlin

I saw you can use a list view to list any view object. But in most of code examples they use a recycler view.
So my question is: When you could use a list view instead of a recycler view ?.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview
hope this helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `RecyclerView` widget is a more advanced and flexible version of `ListView`.

- `RecyclerView` was created as a `ListView` improvement,
- In the `RecyclerView` model, several different components work together to display your data. The overall container for your user interface is a `RecyclerView` object that you add to your layout.
- `RecyclerView` drastically improve performance
- The `RecyclerView` fills itself with views provided by a layout manager that you provide.
- Advantages of `RecyclerView` is

  - Efficiently Reuses cells while scrolling up/down
  - Decouples list from its container
  - Animations are decoupled and delegated to `ItemAnimator`
- RecyclerView is a more flexible control for handling "list data" that follows patterns of delegation of concerns and leaves for itself only one task - recycling items

Comment: ListView also recycles item views, so that specifically isn't an advantage.