# How do I prevent it from doing all of them when I make changes in the viewholder?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm doing a product sales project. I am using the codes below for the product list, but I want to prevent other products from being affected when I click on one. How can I resolve this?

My Activity class:

```
public class ProductListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<ClassListItems> itemArrayList;  //List items Array
    private MyAppAdapter myAppAdapter; //Array Adapter
    private ListView listView; // Listview
    private boolean success = false; // boolean
    private ConnectionHelper connectionClass; //Connection Class Variable
    private ImageButton btnComplete;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView); //Listview Declaration
        connectionClass = new ConnectionHelper(); // Connection Class Initialization
        itemArrayList = new ArrayList<ClassListItems>(); // Arraylist Initialization
        btnComplete = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnComplete);

        btnComplete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    /*Orfiche gl = (Orfiche) getApplicationContext();
                    gl.setAmount("0");*/
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Calling Async Task
        SyncData orderData = new SyncData();
        orderData.execute("");



    }
    // Async Task has three overrided methods,
    private class SyncData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        String msg = "Internet/DB_Credentials/Windows_FireWall_TurnOn Error, See Android Monitor in the bottom For details!";
        ProgressDialog progress;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() //Starts the progress dailog
        {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(ProductListActivity.this, "Synchronising",
                    "Listview Loading! Please Wait...", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings)  // Connect to the database, write query and add items to array list
        {
            try
            {
                Connection conn = connectionClass.connection(); //Connection Object
                if (conn == null)
                {
                    success = false;
                }
                else {
                    // Change below query according to your own database.
                    String query = "";

                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                    if (rs != null) // if resultset not null, I add items to itemArraylist using class created
                    {
                        while (rs.next())
                        {
                            try {
                                itemArrayList.add(new ClassListItems(rs.getString("NAME"),rs.getString("CODE"),rs.getString("GERCEK_STOK")));
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        msg = "Found";
                        success = true;
                    } else {
                        msg = "No Data found!";
                        success = false;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
                msg = writer.toString();
                success = false;
            }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) // disimissing progress dialoge, showing error and setting up my listview
        {
            progress.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(ProductListActivity.this, msg + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (success == false)
            {
            }
            else {
                try {
                    myAppAdapter = new MyAppAdapter(itemArrayList, ProductListActivity.this);
                    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                    listView.setAdapter(myAppAdapter);
                } catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }

            }
        }
    }

    public class MyAppAdapter extends BaseAdapter         //has a class viewholder which holds
    {
        public class ViewHolder
        {
            TextView textName, textCode, textStock;
            EditText edtAmount;
            Button productAdd;
        }

        public List<ClassListItems> parkingList;

        public Context context;
        ArrayList<ClassListItems> arraylist;

        private MyAppAdapter(List<ClassListItems> apps, Context context)
        {
            this.parkingList = apps;
            this.context = context;
            arraylist = new ArrayList<ClassListItems>();
            arraylist.addAll(parkingList);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return parkingList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) // inflating the layout and initializing widgets
        {

            View rowView = convertView;
            ViewHolder viewHolder= null;
            if (rowView == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_items, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.textName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
                viewHolder.textCode = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textCode);
                viewHolder.textStock = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textStock);
                viewHolder.edtAmount = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.edtAmount);
                viewHolder.productAdd = (Button ) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else
            {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            // here setting up names and images
            viewHolder.textName.setText(parkingList.get(position).getName()+"");
            viewHolder.textCode.setText(parkingList.get(position).getCode()+"");
            viewHolder.textStock.setText(parkingList.get(position).getStock()+"");
            viewHolder.edtAmount.getText();


            ViewHolder finalViewHolder = viewHolder;
            View finalRowView = rowView;

            ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

            rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    BottomSheetDialog bottomSheet = new BottomSheetDialog();
                    bottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                            "ModalBottomSheet");
                    String name,code;
                    double amount;
                    name = finalViewHolder.textName.getText().toString();
                    code = finalViewHolder.textCode.getText().toString();
                    amount = Double.parseDouble(finalViewHolder.edtAmount.getText().toString());

                    OrfLine orfLine = new OrfLine();
                    orfLine.setName(name);
                    System.out.println("ProductList : "+ orfLine.getName());
                    orfLine.setCode(code);
                    orfLine.setAmount(amount);



                    finalViewHolder.textName.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

                                }

            });

            return rowView;
        }
    }
    
}
```

*activity_product_list.xml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity.ProductListActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Search" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search_blue" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnComplete"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" />
</LinearLayout>``


*activity_list_items*

    enter  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/cardview_dark_background"
    tools:context=".Activity.ListItemsActivity">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textCode"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textName"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="TextView" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtAmount"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textStock"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

For example, when you click on an item in the onclick event, 5 more texts become green.

Answer (score 0):

Are the product list changing dynamically? I would suggest to change it to a recyclerView. Some [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview)