# Using RecyclerView with Card

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I have some RecyclerView with Card items. And on preLollipop devices it looks fine. But on Lollipop it looks without any spacing between child cards. I tried to use margin and padding, but it didn't help. When I use margin on lollipop it looks fine, but with the same margin on preLollipop spacing is very big.
Once again: why is there different spacings? Which property should I use to fix it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is happening because on L, shadows are outside the the View bounds but pre-L, they are inside the View (unfortunately there is no real shadow support pre-L).

If you want CardView to have same spacing on L as well, set [cardUseCompatPadding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#attr_android.support.v7.cardview:cardUseCompatPadding) to true.

Answer (score 15):

yigit's answer was helpful but didn't have much detail so I'm adding some here for future viewers of this post.

Here is an example of how I got this working (not obvious from linked [android site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#attr_android.support.v7.cardview:cardUseCompatPadding) in yigit's answer).

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    // Other layouts and views here

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The card_view needing an underscore and to use the res-auto schema wasn't obvious.

There is a good example of this in the [Material Design Training](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#CardView).

Comment: You're missing a closing tag in your CardView. I wanted to fix it but I need to edit at least 6 characters :( (and there was nothing else I could think of changing) - would be great if you could correct it :)

Comment: Jepp looking good and thank you for the detailed answer :) ! Though I had to remove that card_view:cardUseCompatPadding - as it wasnt being resolved properly. Not sure that was becaue the library was missing at the time but if it really does not work I'll get back to you. Though I think it was related to another issue and if you tested it, it should be fine I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had to create a layout-v21 folder, which will be used by lollipop devices, and duplicate the layout adding the margin/padding I needed to space it out correctly.

That way when your app is launched on lollipop the layout will be read in from the layout-v21 folder with the correct space added, and any other device will go to your standard layout file where the space isn't needed to be explicitly set.

Hope this helps.