# How to define the number of items in the Horizontal recycleview in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Here is how I construct the recycle view

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    ItemData itemsData[] = { new ItemData("Help",R.drawable.profile_pic),
            new ItemData("Delete",R.drawable.profile_pic),
            new ItemData("Cloud",R.drawable.profile_pic),
            new ItemData("Favorite",R.drawable.profile_pic),
            new ItemData("Like",R.drawable.profile_pic),
            new ItemData("Rating",R.drawable.profile_pic)};


    LinearLayoutManager l = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(l);

    MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(itemsData);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

It works but the problem is it show only 1 item per time, how to change to 2 item? that means , the icon should be 50% of the screen width and total have 2 icons per page

Like this (no need of divider):

```
icon1 | icon2
```

XML (Main Activity)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hmkcode.android.recyclerview.MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

XML (item)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp">

    <!-- icon -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_pic" />

    <!-- title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for helping

**Update :**

Notice The app only have potarit orientation so can ignore the case for landscape

Current result:

[image]

What I would like to achieve similar to 
[image]

And GridLayoutManager is not the exact behavior

```
 GridLayoutManager g = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: is it scrollable? Can you please share the screenshot?

Comment: updated the current and desire result

Comment: Why aren't you using `GridView` or `GridLayoutManager`?

Comment: would you mind provide some example /reference ? thanks a lot

Comment: Try changing `GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL` to `GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL` and

Comment: thanks but no luck, the scroll direction change to vertical

Comment: which is the test device you are using ? If it is an emulator then what is its resolution and screen size?

Comment: Why do you prefer `GridLayoutManager` for this case..? Do you want to have more rows later? If not, you could try to use a `LinearLayoutManager`. And maybe your items really request to `fill_parent` in its `width`- which would be the reason you can only see one item at first.

Comment: Check `yqritc` answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531996/android-recyclerview-gridlayoutmanager-column-spacing

Comment: The easiest way that I can think of is. Get the screen's width and then using LayoutParams set the width of your item as half of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should extend LinearLayoutManager and override tow method below:

```
/**
     * Measure a child view using standard measurement policy, taking the padding
     * of the parent RecyclerView and any added item decorations into account.
     *
     * <p>If the RecyclerView can be scrolled in either dimension the caller may
     * pass 0 as the widthUsed or heightUsed parameters as they will be irrelevant.</p>
     *
     * @param child Child view to measure
     * @param widthUsed Width in pixels currently consumed by other views, if relevant
     * @param heightUsed Height in pixels currently consumed by other views, if relevant
     */
public void measureChild(View child, int widthUsed, int heightUsed) {
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams lpTmp = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
    final RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(screenWidth/2,lpTmp.height);
    int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MainActivity.screenWidth /2 , View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(lp.height , View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    child.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
}

/**
 * Measure a child view using standard measurement policy, taking the padding
 * of the parent RecyclerView, any added item decorations and the child margins
 * into account.
 *
 * <p>If the RecyclerView can be scrolled in either dimension the caller may
 * pass 0 as the widthUsed or heightUsed parameters as they will be irrelevant.</p>
 *
 * @param child Child view to measure
 * @param widthUsed Width in pixels currently consumed by other views, if relevant
 * @param heightUsed Height in pixels currently consumed by other views, if relevant
 */
public void measureChildWithMargins(View child, int widthUsed, int heightUsed) {
    super.measureChildWithMargins(child,widthUsed,heightUsed);
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams lpTmp = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
    final RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(screenWidth/2,lpTmp.height);
    int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MainActivity.screenWidth / 2, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(lp.height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    child.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
}
```

the code above are very simple,just a demo,and the number is **2**.you can customize the codes according to your needs. hope these help to you;

Comment: code snippet creates required effect for width but it is not producing desired effects for height. Using this exact same code snippet, recyclerview row item takes entire height of screen. any solution for this problem?

Comment: never mind. found the solution. instead of passing heightspec in     child.measure(-,-), i pass heightUsed variable(not using the height calculated with makeMeasureSpec).

Answer (score 1):

Use this class instead of LinearLayoutManager.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

/**
 * Created by Islam Salah.
 * <p>
 * https://github.com/IslamSalah
 * islamsalah007@gmail.com
 */

public class CustomLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

private Context mContext;
private int spanCount;

public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void measureChild(View child, int widthUsed, int heightUsed) {
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams lpTmp = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
    final RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(measureScreenWidth(mContext) / spanCount, lpTmp.height);
    int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(measureScreenWidth(mContext) / spanCount, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(lp.height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    child.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
}

@Override
public void measureChildWithMargins(View child, int widthUsed, int heightUsed) {
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams lpTmp = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
    final RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(measureScreenWidth(mContext) / spanCount, lpTmp.height);
    int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(measureScreenWidth(mContext) / spanCount, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(lp.height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    child.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
}

private int measureScreenWidth(Context context) {
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point point = new Point();
    display.getSize(point);

    return point.x;
}

public int getSpanCount() {
    return spanCount;
}

public void setSpanCount(int spanCount) {
    this.spanCount = spanCount;
}
```