# How to set different background with different column with RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager?

Tags: android-recyclerview, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

I have a RecyclerView using StaggeredGridLayoutManager, 2 columns for example, I want to set different backgrounds for the first column and second column,  how to do this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you include the adapter code?

Answer (score 1):

Base on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35226600/5157066), I guess you can try:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams lp =
            (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();

    switch (lp.getSpanIndex()) {
        case 0:
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;
        case 1:
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not ok, the result is always StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams#INVALID_SPAN_ID.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by set a custom `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`, override the method `getItemOffsets` and use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams#getSpanIndex`to set different backgrounds.