# Remove default spacing in recycler view grid layout

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I'm using `StaggeredGridLayout` manager for recycler view

```
mStaggerGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager
                .VERTICAL);
```

Now, I want to remove default spacing there is between columns and rows. Something like in this image but with only 2 columns.

[image]

Comment: what is your viewholder layout?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531996/android-recyclerview-gridlayoutmanager-column-spacing

Answer (score 1):

You have to play around with margin. Not the padding.

The StaggeredGridLayoutManager sets a default margin of "30dp" for each grid item.

It can be changed as follows,

```
class StaggeredListDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    public StaggeredListDecoration() {

    }
    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        BaseCard.CARD_TYPE viewType = (BaseCard.CARD_TYPE)view.getTag();
            ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin = 0;
            ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).rightMargin = 0;
            ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).topMargin = 0;
            ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin= 0;
    }
}
```