# Using a GridlayoutManager how can i make 3 imageViews fill the devices width?

Tags: java, android, containers

I just need to know how to make the images completely fill the devices width because currently there are ugly white gaps between the imags? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this question may help you [Android Recyclerview GridLayoutManager column spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531996/android-recyclerview-gridlayoutmanager-column-spacing)

you can use `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` to control the space between grid, the space can even be negative.

Comment: Thanks for not being a jackass friend =)