# Draw empty cells in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

In my case I have recycler view with `Grid Layout Manager` and custom `Decorator`. In every row(which have 3 column maximum) can be from 1 to 3 items.

The question is how to draw empty cells in case when count of items in the line are one or two? `Warning`!!! It’s not a `lastRow`!

Example:
`Span` count in row 3, elements from collection to draw = 2 how to draw empty cell in 3rd column?
`Span` count in row 3, elements from collection to draw = 1 how to draw empty cell in 2nd and 3rd columns?

Comment: I can think of adding 'dummy' empty data (null) and when the data is null, drawing an empty field in your adapter. Maybe someone else knows of a better solution :D

Comment: @Vucko Thanks for reply bro, in my case this is a bad option so I asked the question in search of a more exotic solution. Since the search in Google did not lead to anything.

Comment: How about the 2nd answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531996/android-recyclerview-gridlayoutmanager-column-spacing/28533234)

Comment: Can you tell what's your use case? What's the point of drawing those empty cells?

Answer (score 1):

Adapter for Recyclerview has to know about the view. For this purpose we use `getItemViewType`.By getting view type we can add any view to the recyclerview.

```
public class MainRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private final static int ADD_VIEW_HOLDER = 0;
private final static int EMPTY_VIEW_HOLDER = 1;

public List<DataList> mDrinkItems;


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position== mDrinkItems.size()-1)
        return EMPTY_VIEW_HOLDER;
    else
        return ADD_VIEW_HOLDER;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    switch (viewType){
        case ADD_VIEW_HOLDER:
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.li_main_content,parent,false);
            return new MainItemHolder(view);
        case EMPTY_VIEW_HOLDER:
            View EMPTYView= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.li_EMPTY_action,parent,false);
            return  new EMPTYViewItemHolder(EMPTYView);
            default:
                 return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int size= mDrinkItems.size();
    switch (getItemViewType(position)){
        case ADD_VIEW_HOLDER:
            ((MainItemHolder)holder).bindData(mDrinkItems.get(position),position,size);
            break;
        case EMPTY_VIEW_HOLDER:
            ((EMPTYViewItemHolder)holder).bindData(mDrinkItems.get(position),position,size);
            break;
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDrinkItems.size();
}

public void setData(List<DailyConsumption> mlist) {
    this.mDrinkItems = mlist;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

When adding data to list to set adapter you get the last index of list to set empty view.

```
List<DataList> mList = new ArrayList<>();
mList.add(mList.size(),new DataList(// whatever you want to add));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by defining different view types.

Just Override the getItemViewType()

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (position < mElementsList.size()) {
                return ITEM_TYPE_NORMAL;
            } else if (position >= mElementsList.size()) {
                return ITEM_TYPE_EMPTY;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then Override onCreateViewHolder

```
onCreateViewHolder(Viewgroup parent, int viewType) {
   if(viewType == ITEM_TYPE_NORMAL) {
     //Use layout for normal type
   } else if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_EMPTY) {
     //Use layout for emptyType
   }
}
```