# staggeredGridLayoutManager with no space in edge only in between columns

Tags: android

I am trying to make grid layout using StaggeredGridLayoutManager with no space in edges only in between column and using span size 2. but no solutions works well.because when positions are change some grid give the space on right or left edge.which is wrong .please help me out.thanks in advance.
with followed link :[Android Recyclerview GridLayoutManager column spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531996/android-recyclerview-gridlayoutmanager-column-spacing)

Comment: Normal and easy way for you is to set space between two columns is to set startMargin and endMargin in your recyclerview row layout

Comment: but it will creates the side space(edge space). i dont want the side space only center space.