# Setting margin using RecyclerView.ItemDecoration is not working in Arbic language

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, item-decoration

i have set margin using RecyclerView.ItemDecoration class and it's working in **English** properly but when i changed my language to **Arabic** its not working 
i have using support for left and right support in menifest file.

Here is **my class**

```
 public class ProductMarginSetting extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {


    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(@NonNull Rect outRect, @NonNull View view, @NonNull RecyclerView parent, @NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);

        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == parent.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1) {
            outRect.right = 24; /* set your margin here */
        }

        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
            outRect.left = 24; /* set your margin here */
        }

      }
    }
```

[Arabic version (not working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRoFl.png) , [English version (working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6lpR.png)

**Thanks**

Comment: Here's an answer that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39941479/5288316

Comment: @Nicolas thanks buddy i got what need, i just modified the above linked code as per my requirement,