# How to remove padding in RecyclerView when using StaggeredGridLayoutManager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, staggeredgridlayout

When I scroll the elements down and then back up, the elements get mixed up and there's a weird padding.
I tried to set the gap strategy to GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS, but then the paddings from the ItemDecoration are displayed incorrectly.

[Before scroll back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYzg7.jpg)

[After scroll back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh5XS.jpg)

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Ac8NARWh

Comment: Try this:-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30701422/6037561