# How to create some margins around a CardView in a Recylerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have the following XML layout file for a cardView that I then put into a Recylerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardView_itemLevel"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"

    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"


    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
    app:contentPaddingBottom="2dp">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_levelImage"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.507"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_bestResultThisLevel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_levelImage" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_CO2SavingsTotalThisLevel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_bestResultThisLevel" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_gasSavingsTotalThisLevel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_CO2SavingsTotalThisLevel" />



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I use the margins value to all directions but still the output looks like this:
[image]

Unfortunately, on the vertical dimension (the fragment is always displayed in landscape mode) there is no margin around the different cardviews. My question is how can I create such a marging.

Comment: You can use item decoration as mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30701422/5696047

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani: Thanks jayesh for your comment. Unfortunately the link is not helpful for me. First of all I want to do it in the XML file and not programmatically. Morover, your suggested solution looks extremely complex and I want to keep thing simple. Thus I don't use it. Still I appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the cardview to another layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="2.5dp">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/tintBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view_center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/use_default_icon"/>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Javier for your answer. While your solution indeed created a margin around the cardview, the overall result is even way worse. The problem with your approach is that the CardView elements are extremely far away from each other, such that you only see two element (so one "column") at at time and you have to scroll to see the next two elements

Comment: You will need to adjust the contents of the cardview,  this particular code is constrained (height/width) in the ViewHolder so that the cards adjust to screen width.  So change ImageView match_parent values to a static value to see the correct results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. Your solution helps.