# Android - How to add a dashed/dotted separator line for RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have used the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31243174/1617737) to create a solid separator line for my `RecyclerView`s.

However, I would like the line to be dashed/dotted.

I already have a `line_dashed.xml` resource that I am using elsewhere in my app:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="line" >

    <stroke
        android:color="@color/blue"
        android:dashGap="12dp"
        android:dashWidth="12dp"
        android:width="1dp" />

</shape>
```

But if I try applying this as the drawable resource that is accessed via my call to `recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getContext()))`, no line is drawn at all.

How to solve so a dashed line is shown?

Answer (score 6):

Just add your drawable resource into this item decorator.

```
DividerItemDecoration decorator = new DividerItemDecoration(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.line_dashed));
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(decorator);
```

and DividerItemDecorator class:

```
public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private Drawable mDivider;
    private int mPaddingLeft;

    public DividerItemDecoration(Drawable divider) {
        mDivider = divider;
        mPaddingLeft = 0;
    }

    public DividerItemDecoration(Drawable divider, int paddingLeft) {
        mDivider = divider;
        mPaddingLeft = paddingLeft;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        if (mDivider == null) return;
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) < 1) return;

        if (getOrientation(parent) == LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL) {
            outRect.top = mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        } else {
            outRect.left = mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        if (mDivider == null) {
            super.onDrawOver(c, parent, state);
            return;
        }

        if (getOrientation(parent) == LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL) {
            final int left = parent.getPaddingLeft() + mPaddingLeft;
            final int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();
            final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();

            for (int i = 1; i < childCount; i++) {
                final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
                final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                final int size = mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
                final int top = child.getTop() - params.topMargin;
                final int bottom = top + size;
                mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
                mDivider.draw(c);
            }

        } else { //horizontal
            final int top = parent.getPaddingTop();
            final int bottom = parent.getHeight() - parent.getPaddingBottom();
            final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();

            for (int i = 1; i < childCount; i++) {
                final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
                final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                final int size = mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth();
                final int left = child.getLeft() - params.leftMargin;
                final int right = left + size;
                mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
                mDivider.draw(c);
            }
        }
    }

    private int getOrientation(RecyclerView parent) {
        if (parent.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) parent.getLayoutManager();
            return layoutManager.getOrientation();
        } else
            throw new IllegalStateException("DividerItemDecoration can only be used with a LinearLayoutManager.");
    }
}
```

Should work I tested it.

**UPDATE:**

```
    android:layerType="software"
```

add this parameter in xml for recyclerView
Also add size into your shape drawable:

```
<size android:height="1dp"/>
```

Comment: Have you test it with datted drawable like @ban-geoengineering showed? Does it really work?

Comment: @Roman_Donchenko Check update, with this changes defenetly works.

Comment: It works for me - with one change: I had to add `<size android:height="2dp"/>` to my **line_dashed.xml** for it to be seen - i.e., I had to specify a height of `2dp` rather than `1dp`. Any ideas why?

Comment: I too have to specify a height of 2dp rather than 1dp to make this work. Any ideas?

Comment: yes exactly, it is working when having height of `2dp` rather than `1dp`.

Comment: @DeepakGoyal - Some device sizes end up getting 1dp translated to < 1 pixel in the conversion math. In instances like this, its usually a good idea to set it to 1px or  2dp like you did.

Comment: it's working but android:layerType="software" disable card view shadow

Answer (score 2):

currently u can use DividerItemDecoration from the box.

```
recyclerView.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@YourFragment.context)
        adapter = this@YourFragment.adapter
        addItemDecoration(
            DividerItemDecoration(
                this@YourFragment.context,
                DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
            ).apply {
                context.getDrawable(R.drawable.divider)?.let {
                    setDrawable(it)
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

Use the next shape XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">

    <size android:height="1dp" />

    <solid android:color="@color/primary" />

    <stroke
        android:width="0.5dp"
        android:color="@color/primary"
        android:dashWidth="5dp"
        android:dashGap="5dp" />
</shape>
```

**Attention**: The stroke width must be less than the height of the line. In another case, the line will be not drawn.

Comment: This bit was key for me:
```
Attention: The stroke width must be less than the height of the line. In another case, the line will be not drawn.
```

Answer (score 0):

Draw dashed line in Android is not so easy deal. Drowable like you showed and even just draw dotted line on canwas (`canvas.drawLine(..., paintWithDashEffect)`) not always works (not for all devices). You may use `android:layerType="software"` or draw path. IMHO, the better solution is to not draw dotted line at all (draw just line). But if you really need dotted line, you can use @fearless answer or somethink like this:

```
public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private Paint mPaint;
private int mDividerSize;

public DividerItemDecoration(int dividerSize) {
    mDividerSize = dividerSize;
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(dividerSize);
    mPaint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{dashGap,dashWidth},0));
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    outRect.bottom = mDividerSize;
}

@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

    int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    Path path = new Path();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

        RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

        int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin + mDividerSize/2;

        path.moveTo(left, top);
        path.lineTo(right, top);
    }
    c.drawPath(path, mPaint);
}

}
```