# How to add divider after a certain ListView item similar to Gmail

Tags: android, listview, navigation, drawer

Similar to how Gmail does it, I would like to add a text divider to my navigation drawer after the (in my case) second item. How can I achieve that? I guess somewhere around

```
mDrawerAdapter = new DrawerAdapter(this, cursor);

        mDrawerList.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mDrawerList.setAdapter(mDrawerAdapter);
                selectDrawerItem(mCurrentDrawerPos);
            }
        });
```

, right?

Thanks!
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your `menu.xml` file ?

Otherwhise to display separator you need to create groups like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group
        android:id="@+id/first_group"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:checked="true"
            android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:icon="@drawable/XX"
            android:title="@string/XXX"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:icon="@drawable/XXX"
            android:title="@string/XXX"/>
    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/second_group"
        android:checkableBehavior="none">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item3"
            android:icon="@drawable/XXX"
            android:title="@string/XXX" >
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: My menu is still created in code because it is dynamic (RSS reader)

Comment: How do you initialize your menu ? Do you use addSubMenu() method to set an item?

Comment: you can add  divider in your layout row and after that in adapter write a condition if position equal to 0 then show View Divider other wise hide divider..

Comment: @HiteshKushwah This is what I actually figured out a few minutes ago myself and what I am currently working on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options form where I sit.

1. Use a separate layout file for this view which would mean having more than one model type of data backing your Adapter and inflating the correct layout depending on the type. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)
2. Use Item decoration to add a line to the bottom of a chosen layout or layouts. [this post should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31242812/how-can-a-divider-line-be-added-in-an-android-recyclerview)