# How to reduce space between items of RecyclerView in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented Horizontal RecyclerView for Images. Horizontal navigation work fine but unwanted space is drawn between two items of RecyclerView.

[image: Unwanted space is der on Left side of image item in RecyclerView]
[image: Unwanted space between two images in RecyclerView]

RecyclerView item layout-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My RecyclerView layout-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerView Setup-

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
HlistViewAdapter adapter = new HlistViewAdapter(pArray);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

My RecyclerView Adapter-

```
public class HlistViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HlistViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

ArrayList<String> pathArray;

public HlistViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> pathArray){
    this.pathArray = pathArray;
}

@Override
public HlistViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.hlist_item_layout, null);

    // create ViewHolder

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HlistViewAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathArray.get(i)));
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView imgViewIcon;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        imgViewIcon = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return pathArray.size();
}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618829/how-to-add-dividers-and-spaces-between-items-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited answer after chat with user**

the problem was the size of the images being too different to the different android devices, and the impossibility to stretch them to prevent the empty spaces. given that, i recommend the use of a ViewPager instead of a RecyclerView, having that it will provide the same functionality buth with a better controll on how the imageView will react  with different sized images.

http://codetheory.in/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter/

Comment: :recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); gives same result

Comment: Yeah I have HlistViewAdapter. Do u want me to post Adapter code snippet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88547/discussion-between-kevz-and-cpteric).