# Android Horizontal RecyclerView wrap_content

Tags: android

I'm making horizontal RecyclerView with photos in it, and I have faced up with wrap_parent problem. If I put in my `View width = wrap_content`, it is screenWidth width, although image consumes very small space. If I change `wrap_content` to some value it works perfectly.RecyclerView is 75dp height and `match_parent`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="@drawable/card_foreground">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bitmap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVKuz.png)

Dark blue is screen and light blue is photos. Problem is I have case 1 when I set view to `wrap_content`.

**SOLUTION:**

I have solved this problem recently, there is some bug or something simmilar, when you try to have on scaled ImageView wrap_parent. It doesn't work very well.
To solve this, I have resized every photo to final size before put it in RecyclerView. In adition, I have some small space between ImageView again, and I have solved by adding `padding=0` and `margin=0` to childern of RecyclerView.

Comment: What you exactly want?

Comment: you use too many shortcuts in your description; please add at least one screenshot to show us how it works and how it should work

Comment: I want wrap_parent, I want to have photos in line without any space between them.

Comment: like @ChiragSavsani I hardly understand what you expect

Comment: `wrap_parent`? or `match_parent` ???

Comment: I have put screenshots please check it

Comment: All images are have same dimension?

Comment: Not excatly same but near the same, but every photo is need to be scaled to fit into height

Comment: Then use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in `ImageView`.

Comment: But If you use `wrap_content` in `ImageView` and Image size is different, then all images not look same size.

Comment: @Filip V: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346813/how-to-reduce-space-between-items-of-recyclerview-in-android. I Think u r facing the same problem.

Comment: I have solved problem, thanks for help. I have put my solution in post, check it.

Answer (score 0):

1. First solution: LinearLayout `weight` attribute

As long as you would use for that view `LinearLayout` you may use for all of your `ImageView` views this attribute:

```
    android:layout_weight="{number_value}"
```

Shortly, if you add for all of your `ImageView` views the same value for `weight` they would get calculated the same space, but not more than their parent view attributes.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Read please this issue:

[What does android:layout_weight mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean)

If you still face the problem, give me a call.

2. Second solution: ImageView `scale` attribute

   For ImageView you can use `scaleX`, `scaleY`, `scaleType` attributes. For having the same height you should use the same `scaleY` value for all your `ImageView` items.

Think also about using `TableLayout` or `GridLayout` for this purpose.

Comment: You can add layout_weight on RecylerView children

Comment: Oh sorry, I wanted to write "You can't", however I've solved this problem check my solution if you are interested in. Thanks.

Comment: so you had a padding and margin and  you didn't write about them? :-)

Comment: No, I have unscaled images, and there is problem with wrap_parent in RecylerView when imageView need to scale it. And additional problem was padding which I haven't set anywhere but when i set on zero it works