# Android RecyclerView ItemDecoration

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to create an custom `ItemDecoration` like this one: Gap between groups, and line between group items.
[image: This is a screen shot of WeChat App]

I think the gap can be an empty view with different view type from the common item in my adapter. But as to the divider line, I don't know how to control them.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: * Please look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618829/how-to-add-dividers-and-spaces-between-items-in-recyclerview). It might help you getting better idea.

Comment: you can use cardview to solve above problem