# Gap between the images that are laoding from jsons

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

hi i have a problem friends i am passing the text and the images from the Json using volley library and recycler view with horizontal orientation everything working fine but i am getting more gap in between the images because of that navigation drawer also effecting      [this the image of the home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smJ3E.png)

[Here is navigation drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTDo4.png)

This adapter featured products

```
public class FeaturedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
private Context context;
private List<Data> fpdata;

public FeaturedAdapter(Context context, List<Data> fpdata) {
    this.context = context;
    this.fpdata = fpdata;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View fpds = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singlefeatured, parent,false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(fpds);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Data feature=fpdata.get(position);

    holder.netfp.setImageUrl(feature.getFpimage(),imageLoader);
    holder.title.setText(feature.getTitle());
    holder.price.setText(feature.getPrice());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return fpdata.size();
}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618829/how-to-add-dividers-and-spaces-between-items-in-recyclerview. You can use item decorators to specify spacing between items

Comment: this looks more like a problem with your imageview properties. try `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in your item layout on your imageview