# How to avoid unwanted space between items while using RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

While trying to implement RecyclerView i'm getting large chunk of white space between items...

### RecyclerView layout:-

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/crime_reycler_view"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

### My RecyclerView item layout-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/list_item_crime_solved_check_box"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

 <TextView
      android:id="@+id/list_item_crime_title_text_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/list_item_crime_solved_check_box"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      tools:text="Crime Title"/>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/list_item_date_text_view"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/list_item_crime_solved_check_box"
     android:layout_below="@id/list_item_crime_title_text_view"
     tools:text="Crime Date"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### My RecyclerView setup-

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list, container, false);

    mCrimeRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.crime_reycler_view);

    mCrimeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        mSubtitleVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE);
    }
```

### My RecyclerView adapter

```
private class CrimeAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<CrimeHolder>
{
    private List<Crime> mCrimes;

    public CrimeAdapter (List<Crime> crime)
    {
        mCrimes = crime;
    }

    //This method is called to create a view
    @Override
    public CrimeHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = layoutInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, parent, false);

        return new CrimeHolder(view);
    }

    //binds them together
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CrimeHolder holder, int position)
    {
        Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
        holder.bindCrime(crime);
    }

    private void setCrimes (List<Crime> crimes)
    {
        mCrimes = crimes;
    }

    //RecycleView Calls this method to get the size of mCrimes
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCrimes.size();
    }
}
```

[This is how it looks on moblile after adding items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5Ibq.jpg)

Comment: this might be something you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618829/how-to-add-dividers-and-spaces-between-items-in-recyclerview

Comment: change your Item's RelativeLayout's height to wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your `RecyclerView` item's `android:layout_height` property to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

because you set in **My RecyclerView item layout** is a root layout 
set is **android:layout_height**  is match_parent

replace this code and enjoy him !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

 <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/list_item_crime_solved_check_box"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

 <TextView
      android:id="@+id/list_item_crime_title_text_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/list_item_crime_solved_check_box"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      tools:text="Crime Title"/>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/list_item_date_text_view"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/list_item_crime_solved_check_box"
     android:layout_below="@id/list_item_crime_title_text_view"
     tools:text="Crime Date"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```