# How can I insert a Title row in my custom adaptor list

Tags: java, android

I want to create a custom row adapter to my Android application.
So I have build this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/medication"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/instructions"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/medication"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/startDate"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/instructions"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/active"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/startDate"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I have build this adaptor class "MedicationAdapter.java":

```
public class MedicationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MedicationAdapter.MyMedicationViewHolder> {

    private List<Medication> moviesList;

    public class MyMedicationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView medication, instruction, startDate,active;

        public MyMedicationViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            medication = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.medication);
            instruction = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.instructions);
            startDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.startDate);
            active = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.active);
        }
    }


    public MedicationAdapter(List<Medication> moviesList) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyMedicationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.medications_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyMedicationViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyMedicationViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Medication medication = moviesList.get(position);
        holder.medication.setText(medication.getDrugInfo().getDisplayName());
        holder.instruction.setText(medication.getFrequency()+" "+ medication.getDose());
        holder.startDate.setText(medication.getDateStart());
        holder.active.setText("SI");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList.size();
    }
}
```

Now if I try to run my Android application, I can see my activity like this:

[image]

Now I want to insert a title Text in the head of this list, and I want to insert a border line to every cell.

It is possible to do this?

regards

Comment: provide full xml file.

Comment: Do u want to insert title for evry cell..??

Comment: no, I want to insert a title only at the first row

Comment: Then add TextView in activity layout, above of ListView.

Comment: for make the border for each cell. just make the border for you `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Add a TextView above the RecyclerView for the title. And for the border line, you can look at ItemDecoration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can implement header for your RecyclerView.
Pls look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26573338/1554094

You can use [item decoration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html). There are answers on same question [How to add dividers and spaces between items in RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618829/how-to-add-dividers-and-spaces-between-items-in-recyclerview)

Or you can just add view with height 1dp at bottom of you view item

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code to set header in recyclerview

```
 public class HeaderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
String[] data;

public HeaderAdapter(String[] data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
        return new VHItem(null);
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
        return new VHHeader(null);
    }

    throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof VHItem) {
        String dataItem = getItem(position);
        //cast holder to VHItem and set data
    } else if (holder instanceof VHHeader) {
        //cast holder to VHHeader and set data for header.
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.length + 1;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isPositionHeader(position))
        return TYPE_HEADER;

    return TYPE_ITEM;
}

private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
    return position == 0;
}

private String getItem(int position) {
    return data[position - 1];
}

class VHItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView title;

    public VHItem(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

class VHHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Button button;

    public VHHeader(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

for border in Recyclerview

```
  recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,  LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```

// set the adapter
   recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

```
public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[]{
        android.R.attr.listDivider
};

public static final int HORIZONTAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL;

public static final int VERTICAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL;

private Drawable mDivider;

private int mOrientation;

public DividerItemDecoration(Context context, int orientation) {
    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS);
    mDivider = a.getDrawable(0);
    a.recycle();
    setOrientation(orientation);
}

public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
    if (orientation != HORIZONTAL_LIST && orientation != VERTICAL_LIST) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid orientation");
    }
    mOrientation = orientation;
}

@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        drawVertical(c, parent);
    } else {
        drawHorizontal(c, parent);
    }
}

public void drawVertical(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    final int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
        final int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}

public void drawHorizontal(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int top = parent.getPaddingTop();
    final int bottom = parent.getHeight() - parent.getPaddingBottom();

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int left = child.getRight() + params.rightMargin;
        final int right = left + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight());
    } else {
        outRect.set(0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0);
    }
}
```

}