# Margin between items in recycler view Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Hi I am Following this tutorial:

http://www.journaldev.com/10024/android-recyclerview-and-cardview-example-tutorial

Now I am facing a weird issue the margin between each `CardView` item inside `RecyclerView` is way too much.

**ISSUE**

How to reduce the Margin between each item of `CardView` placed inside `RecyclerView`?

[image]

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I faced similar issue, with RelativeLayout as the root element for each row in the recyclerview.

To solve the issue, find the xml file that holds each row and make sure that the root element's height is `wrap_content` NOT `match_parent`.

Comment: yes this worked, Had to remove parent relative layout match parent to wrap content

Comment: Works also if you had "fill_parent" for the Relative Layout and change it to "wrap_content". Works perfectly. Great!

Comment: For Image only, wrap_content not working.@maher

Answer (score 53):

I made a class to manage this issue. This class set different margins for the items inside the recyclerView: only the first row will have a top margin and only the first column will have left margin.

```
public class RecyclerViewMargin extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
private final int columns;
private int margin;

/**
 * constructor
 * @param margin desirable margin size in px between the views in the recyclerView
 * @param columns number of columns of the RecyclerView
 */
public RecyclerViewMargin(@IntRange(from=0)int margin ,@IntRange(from=0) int columns ) {
    this.margin = margin;
    this.columns=columns;

}

/**
 * Set different margins for the items inside the recyclerView: no top margin for the first row
 * and no left margin for the first column.
 */
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view,
                           RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

    int position = parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view);
    //set right margin to all
    outRect.right = margin;
    //set bottom margin to all
    outRect.bottom = margin;
    //we only add top margin to the first row
    if (position <columns) {
        outRect.top = margin;
    }
    //add left margin only to the first column
    if(position%columns==0){
        outRect.left = margin;
        }
    }
}
```

you can set it in your recyclerview this way

```
 RecyclerViewMargin decoration = new RecyclerViewMargin(itemMargin, numColumns);
 recyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);
```

Comment: @Victor I have issue for the answer, how about if I updating the position of item ? it should refreshing, but it's not. And the item on the bottom whose going on first row will still has margin

Answer (score 45):

1. Find the attribute `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` in **cards_layout.xml** and delete it. Start app and you will find there is no margin between each cardview item.
2. Add margin attributes you like. Ex:

   ```
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
   android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
   ```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me, though it was this only one case where card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" didn't do the job

Answer (score 12):

Instead of using XML to add margin between items in RecyclerView, it's better way to use RecyclerView.ItemDecoration that provide by android framework.

So, I create a library to solve this issue.

https://github.com/TheKhaeng/recycler-view-margin-decoration

[image]

Comment: You have made an awesome Library.Thank you! You saved my day! :)

Comment: simple and awesome library

Comment: I would recommend [SpacingItemDecoration](https://github.com/grzegorzojdana/SpacingItemDecoration) library. This is the best

Answer (score 10):

Use `CardView` in `Recyclerview` Item Layout like this :

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#ACACAC"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:contentPadding="10dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

Answer (score 7):

Use CompatPadding in CardView Item

Answer (score 2):

Try to add [RecyclerView.ItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html)

To know how to do that: [How to add dividers and spaces between items in RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618829/how-to-add-dividers-and-spaces-between-items-in-recyclerview)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in **XML**, jus set `paddingTop`and `paddingLeft` to your `RecyclerView` and equal amount of `layoutMarginBottom` and `layoutMarginRight` to the item you inflate into your `RecyclerView`(or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

For adding space between Two items in recycler View. I just add `marginTop` and `marginBottom` and it works fine.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:elevation="15dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

In XML, to manage margins between items of a RecyclerView, I am doing in this way,
operating on these attributes of detail layout (I am using a RelativeLayout):

- android:layout_marginTop
- android:layout_marginBottom

of course it is also very important to set these attributes:

- android:layout_width="wrap_content"
- android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Here follows a complete example,
this is the layout for the **list of items**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:name="blah.ui.meetings.MeetingEventFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:layout_marginVertical="2dp"
app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
tools:context=".ui.meetings.MeetingEventFragment"
tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_meeting_event" />
```

and this is the **detail layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
android:background="@drawable/background_border_meetings">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/slot_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="slot_type"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

background_border_meetings is just a box:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
    <!-- This is the stroke you want to define -->
    <stroke android:width="4dp"
    android:color="@color/mdtp_line_dark"/>
    <!-- Optional, round your corners -->
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
    android:topRightRadius="2dp" />
    <gradient android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, in my case I used the layout margin in the negative. Maybe not the best idea but it worked.

```
android:layout_marginStart="-8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="-8dp"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

change in Recycler view **match_parent** to **wrap_content**:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycleView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Also change in item layout xml

Make parent layout height **match_parent** to **wrap_content**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```